# why for(;;) instead of while(1)?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “for(;;)”  faster than “while (TRUE)”? If not, why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it)

Why use the ugly `for(;;)` syntax instead of the slightly better looking `while(true)` loop?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no advantage to `for(;;)` over `while(1)`.
Use `while(1)`, because it's easier to comprehend (imho). I've never seen a `for(;;)` used before, and it may be confusing to others who view your code, and may wonder the same thing you just asked.

EDIT: Here's a link: [while (1) Vs. for (;;) Is there a speed difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference)

It basically says that they both generate the same code. In assembly, it's `jmp ...`.

Comment: I think PC-Lint gives a warning for while(1), while it does not for for(;;).

Answer (score 2):

Less typing? It's shorter. And on a QWERTY keyboard, typing `for` alternates between the left and right hand, and `while` has three consecutive letters that are typed with the right hand, making typing it potentially even slower.

Comment: What is it about C programmers and idiot levels of micro-optimizations?  If you're focusing on the speed of your typing, you're doing programming wrong.

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: Whoosh...

Comment: While you may be (and probably are) joking, I have heard this kind of foolishness before.  Vi/m advocates use this kind of reasoning for evangelizing Vi/m, for example, and I have heard from more than a few C programmers that they can't stand the Wirthian family of languages (Pascal, the Modulas, the Oberons, Ada etc.) because it takes too much effort to type `BEGIN ... END` over `{ ... }`.  Can you forgive me for confusing your joke with these very tragic realities?  ;)