# What does "while True" mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

```
def play_game(word_list):
    hand = deal_hand(HAND_SIZE) # random init
    while True:
        cmd = raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: ')
        if cmd == 'n':
            hand = deal_hand(HAND_SIZE)
            play_hand(hand.copy(), word_list)
            print
        elif cmd == 'r':
            play_hand(hand.copy(), word_list)
            print
        elif cmd == 'e':
            break
        else:
            print "Invalid command."
```

While WHAT is True?

I reckon saying 'while true' is shorthand, but for what? While the variable 'hand' is being assigned a value? And what if the variable 'hand' is not being assigned a value?

Comment: True is sort of an alias for 1. A sort of related question I asked can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference

Comment: @Copas, `True` is not an alias for `1`. Although in many languages `1` evaluates to the truth in boolean context.

Comment: adamse: In *some* versions of Python, `True` has been an alias for `1`, no?  Though yes, in the latest versions of Python there is a real boolean type.

Comment: @adamse, @Ken: quoting from [What's new in Python 2.3 - PEP 285](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.3.html#pep-285-a-boolean-type): "A Boolean type was added to Python 2.3. Two new constants were added to the `__builtin__` module, True and False. (True and False constants were added to the built-ins in Python 2.2.1, but the 2.2.1 versions are simply set to integer values of 1 and 0 and aren't a different type.)".

Comment: @adamse In python it is not, however in many languages it is. I considered it to be a more general question. Speaking to a beginner as Baba said he/she was "True is sort of an alias for 1" is perfectly accurate. I agree in Python True is not an alias for 1. I didn't say it was.

Comment: @Baba: Please mark my answer as "accepted" if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: I have an unrelated question.  Is this considered 'pythonic'?  Am I alone in feeling that this is pattern has a bad smell?  I feel that this could be written in a more clear way.

Answer (score 137):

`while True` means loop forever. The `while` statement takes an expression and executes the loop body while the expression evaluates to (boolean) "true". `True` always evaluates to boolean "true" and thus executes the loop body indefinitely. It's an idiom that you'll just get used to eventually! Most languages you're likely to encounter have equivalent idioms.

Note that most languages usually have some mechanism for breaking out of the loop early. In the case of Python it's the `break` statement in the `cmd == 'e'` case of the sample in your question.

Comment: For clarity sake I believe you can do while(true == true) in most languages.  This may help for a new programmer to better understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Chris, `while True==True` is ugly. It is as ugly as `while 'apples'!='oranges'` :)

Comment: @Chris: I can't see how adding syntax will help.

Comment: As one of my teachers pointed out: if you think `true==true` is an improvement, where do you stop?  Wouldn't `(true==true)==true` be even better?

Comment: It's only a clarification for those that don't understand you don't have to have a comparison there, only a boolean. (true==true) isn't better in a general sense, only to explain something. It's not something you'd do it the real world, or any other time.

Comment: I think I've seen this around somewhere. `bool ever = true; for (;ever;) { }`

Comment: If you think `while True == True` is good and `while False == False` is bad, you have misunderstood everything.

Comment: @Chris, eventually one should be aware that a boolean value or variable can be used in place of a logic expression, and "eventually" should be as soon as possible.

Comment: @Mark eventually one should be aware that at times it takes a bit of additional help to get a new programmer to understand boolean logic and the like.  All I was trying to do was help him understand it.

Answer (score 65):

> my question: while WHAT is True?

While `True` is `True`.

The while loop will run as long as the conditional expression evaluates to `True`.

Since `True` always evaluates to `True`, the loop will run indefinitely, until something within the loop `return`s or `break`s.

Comment: This is python. There is no parenthesized expression ;P

Comment: heh, good point. I'm not used to thinking in Python. Although I suppose you _could_ put parens around it if you wanted...

Answer (score 12):

while `True` is true -- ie always.  This is an infinite loop

Note the important distinction here between `True` which is a keyword in the language denoting a constant value of a particular type, and 'true' which is a mathematical concept.

Comment: Technically speaking, you're wrong. The construct means "while true is not false". You can see the distinction if you write `while(5)` in C, where there are no proper booleans. It doesn't mean `while(5==1)`, it means `while(5!=0)`.

Comment: I think it's more appropriate to say 'indefinite loop;' the assumption must be that the loop will be interrupted by a break or return at some point. Truly 'infinite' loops are programmer error; 'indefinite loops' are created by design.

Comment: @Blindy: in a weakly-typed language with automatic casting, you can say x 'evaluates to' y... it's not while 5 is not strictly equal to 0, it's while 5 is loosely equal to True.

Comment: @Blindy, `while(5)` in C means while `5` is true, not while its `true` or `0`, which is something completely different.  `5` is always true.  In general, when languages have a keyword `true`, its a constant that is true, but not the only constant that is true.  Similarly `false` is not necessarily the only value that is false.

Answer (score 10):

> my question: while WHAT is True?

Everything inside the () of the while statement is going to be evaluated as a boolean. Meaning it gets converted into either true or false.

Consider in the statement `while(6 > 5)`

It first evaluates the expression `6 > 5` which is `true` so is the same as saying `while(true)`

Anything that is not FALSE, 0, an emptry string "", null, or undefined is likely to be evaluated to true.

When I first started programming I used to do things like `if(foo == true)`, I didn't realise that was virtually the same thing as `if(foo)`.

So when you say `while(true)` its like are saying `while(true == true)`

So to answer you question: While TRUE is True.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, I suppose it could be interpreted as

```
do
...
while cmd  != 'e'
```

Answer (score 3):

`True` is always `True`, so `while True` will loop forever.

The `while` keyword takes an expression, and loops while the expression is true. `True` is an expression that is always true.

As a possibly clarifying example, consider the following:

```
a = 1
result = a == 1
```

Here, `a == 1` will return `True`, and hence put `True` into `result`. Hence,

```
a = 1
while a == 1:
  ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
while True:
  ...
```

provided you don't alter the value of `a` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: `True` isn't *always* `True`, e.g. `True = False`. ;-)

Comment: @jathanism- Truth is truth, To the end of reckoning.

Answer (score 3):

Formally, `True` is a Python [built-in constant](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html) of [bool](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bool) type.

You can use [Boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html) on bool types (at the interactive python prompt for example) and [convert numbers](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=bool#bool) into bool types:

```
>>> print not True
False
>>> print not False
True
>>> print True or False
True
>>> print True and False
False
>>> a=bool(9)
>>> print a
True
>>> b=bool(0)
>>> print b
False
>>> b=bool(0.000000000000000000000000000000000001)
>>> print b
True
```

And there are "gotcha's" potentially with what you see and what the Python compiler sees:

```
>>> n=0
>>> print bool(n)
False
>>> n='0'
>>> print bool(n)
True
>>> n=0.0
>>> print bool(n)
False
>>> n="0.0"
>>> print bool(n)
True
```

As a hint of how Python stores bool types internally, you can cast bool types to integers and True will come out to be 1 and False 0:

```
>>> print True+0
1
>>> print True+1
2
>>> print False+0
0
>>> print False+1
1
```

In fact, Python `bool` type is a subclass of Python's `int` type:

```
>>> type(True)
<type 'bool'>
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
```

The more important part of your question is "What is `while True`?" is 'what is True', and an important corollary: What is false?

First, for every language you are learning, learn what the language considers 'truthy' and 'falsey'. Python considers [Truth](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html) slightly differently than [Perl Truth](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol4_2/tpj0402-0002.html) for example. Other languages have [slightly different concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) of true / false. **Know what your language considers to be True and False for different operations and flow control to avoid many headaches later!**

There are many algorithms where you want to process something until you find what you are looking for. Hence the [infinite loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop) or indefinite loop. Each language tend to have its own idiom for these constructs. Here are common C infinite loops, which also work for Perl:

```
for(;;) { /* loop until break */ }

/* or */

while (1) {
   return if (function(arg) > 3);
}
```

The `while True:` form is common in Python for indefinite loops with some way of breaking out of the loop. Learn Python [flow control](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) to understand how you break out of `while True` loops. Unlike most languages, for example, Python can have an `else` clause on a loop. There is an example in the last link.

Answer (score 2):

A `while` loop takes a conditional argument (meaning something that is generally either true or false, or can be interpreted as such), and only executes while the condition yields `True`.

As for `while True`? Well, the simplest true conditional is `True` itself! So this is an infinite loop, usually good in a game that requires lots of looping. (More common from my perspective, though, is to set some sort of "done" variable to false and then making that true to end the game, and the loop would look more like `while not done:` or whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

While most of these answers are correct to varying degrees, none of them are as succinct as I would like.

Put simply, using `while True:` is just a way of running a loop that will continue to run until you explicitly break out of it using `break` or `return`.  Since True will always evaluate to True, you have to force the loop to end when you want it to.

```py
while True:
    # do stuff

    if some_condition:
        break

    # do more stuff - code here WILL NOT execute when `if some_condition:` evaluates to True
```

While normally a loop would be set to run until the while condition is false, or it reaches a predefined end point:

```py
do_next = True

while do_next:

    # do stuff

    if some_condition:
        do_next = False

    # do more stuff - code here WILL execute even when `if some_condition:` evaluates to True
```

Those two code chunks effectively do the same thing

If the condition your loop evaluates against is possibly a value not directly in your control, such as a user input value, then validating the data and explicitly breaking out of the loop is usually necessary, so you'd want to do it with either method.

The `while True` format is more pythonic since you know that `break` is breaking the loop at that exact point, whereas `do_next = False` could do more stuff before the next evaluation of `do_next`.

Answer (score 1):

In some languages True is just and alias for the number.  You can learn more why this is by reading more about [boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic).

Answer (score 1):

while True mean infinite loop, this usually use by long process.
you can change

```
while True:
```

with

```
while 1:
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: while the loop condition is True.  Which it always is, in this particular bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

`while` loops continue to loop until the condition is false. For instance (pseudocode):

```
i = 0
while i < 10
  i++
```

With each iteration of the loop, `i` will be incremented by 1, until it is 10. At that point, the condition `i < 10` is no longer true, and the loop will complete.

Since the condition in `while True` is explicitly and always `true`, the loop will never end (until it is broken out of some other way, usually by a construct like `break` within the loop body).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing evaluates to `True` faster than `True`. So, it is good if you use `while True` instead of `while 1==1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    ...
```

means infinite loop.

The while statement is often used of a finite loop. But using the constant 'True' guarantees the repetition of the while statement without the need to control the loop (setting a boolean value inside the iteration for example), unless you want to break it.

In fact

```
True == (1 == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

While True means loop will run infinitely is no condition is mentioned inside the while loop that breaks it.

You can break the code using 'break' or 'return'

```
>>> a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> while True:
...     if not a:
...         break
...     print(a.pop(-1))
...
baz
bar
foo
```

Code copied from the realpython.com

Answer (score 0):

## **How to use while True in Python?**

```
# Python program to demonstrate
# while loop with True
  
while True:
    pass
```

If we run the above code then this loop will run infinite number of times. To come out of this loop we will use the **[break statement](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-break-statement/)**  explicitly.

1. With Break Statement

```
weekSalary = 0
dayOfWeek = 1
week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
while(True):
  if(week[dayOfWeek] == "Sunday"):
    print("Week Over, Its holiday!!")
    break
  weekSalary += 2000
  dayOfWeek += 1 

print(str(weekSalary))
```

2. With Return Statement

Since `True` always evaluates to `True` , the loop will run indefinitely, until something within the loop `return`.

```
class Solution:
    def minEatingSpeed(self, piles: List[int], h: int) -> int:
        k = 1
        while True:
            total_time = 0
            for i in piles:
                total_time += ceil(i / k)
            if total_time > h:
                k += 1
            else:
                return k
```

Answer (score -5):

Anything can be taken as True until the opposite is presented. This is the way duality works. It is a way that opposites are compared. Black can be True until white at which point it is False. Black can also be False until white at which point it is True. It is not a state but a comparison of opposite states. If either is True the other is wrong. True does not mean it is correct or is accepted. It is a state where the opposite is always False. It is duality.