# Why does my for loop does not iterate through each element of my list?

Tags: python, oop, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I managed to solve my problem, but I don't understand the problem itself. Yeah, I've been lucky enough to fix it, but it won't be as useful if I don't understand why I had this problem.

When running a for loop inside an object's function, this loop was always skipping one value of the list, just like if the for loop step was set to 2.

Below is a very very simplified and adapted version of my first code, but it gives a good idea of how it works.

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list

    def food_iterator(self):
        while True:
            for element in self.my_list:
                print(element)

Food(['pasta', 'chicken', 'porc', 'cheese', 'lasagna']).food_iterator()
```

When creating a copy of the original list:

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list

    def food_iterator(self):
        my_list_copy = [m for m in self.my_list])

        while True:
            for element in my_list_copy:
                print(element)

Food(['pasta', 'chicken', 'porc', 'cheese', 'lasagna']).food_iterator()
```

it just worked perfectly. But I don't understand why it wasn't working before and why it is now...

I would really appreciate to hear your thoughts!

Comment: The problem you describe happens when you are deleting elements from a list you're iterating over - it doesn't happen when just printing the elements, but the code you posted won't actually run due to indentation problems, so I have no idea what your actual code is.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. Just two sidenotes: [don't use mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument), and a better iterator would be `yield from self.my_list`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you have "while True" in the code but there's no "break", so your code will run endlessly. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754620/what-does-while-true-mean-in-python).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I think that mutable default arguments are the source of my problem. I will take a closer look at this and learn to fix it