# How to break the While True statement on the same error 3 times

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch

I'm currently using the while True loop, but if the same error is repeated 3 times, please tell me how to exit the while True statement. I use python.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: The code was too long to attach

Comment: module [retrying](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a variable keeping track of the last error's type, and a counter for the how many of those occurred, which resets if an error of a different type appeared. If the counter hits 3, then exit accordingly.

```py
last_exception, counter = None, 0
while True:
   try:
      # some error here
      raise ValueError
   except Exception as e:
      if type(e) is not last_exception:
         last_exception, counter = type(e), 0
      counter += 1
      if counter == 3:
         break
```

Comment: What should I do to break if the same error occurs three times in a row?

Comment: Then just reset the counter if it doesn't occur continuously: in the `try` block, after the error-prone code, add `counter = 0`. If the code runs successfully, the consecutive error counter resets.

Edit: Unless you mean that your code may throw different errors, and you would want the loop to terminate if the last 3 errors are identical, then please edit your question and I'll answer accordingly. It'll only involve some extra keeping track of things.

Comment: As you said, if the last three errors are the same, I want to break it.

Comment: @skw0314 Updated my answer to accommodate that.

Answer (score 1):

You just declare a variable outside your loop and initialize to 0, increment it by one each time the loop iterates, and your while loop iterates while it's less than 3

```
i = 0
while i < 3:
  print(i)
  i += 1
```

Edit: I just realised you said while true
Take a look at this
[What does "while True" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754620/what-does-while-true-mean-in-python)

If you have to use a while true then use an if statement to check if i >=3 and then use a break statement to exit the loop if that's true