# Looping Try Statement

Tags: java, exception, loops, logic, try-catch

I am trying to loop a try block every time an exception is thrown.

An example might be when the program prompts for a double and the user enters a string, so, a NumberFormatException is thrown. So the program will request the user to re-enter.

Here's what I am doing currently. Is this the proper way to do so or is there better way?

```
// infinite loop
for (;;)
{     
    try 
    {
        //do something
        break; // if an exception is not thrown. it breaks the loop.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //display the stack trace.
    }

    // restarts the for loop
}
```

Comment: Heh, I dealt with a similar problem in my [blog](http://blog.engineering.vayana.in/case-study-in-dsl-development-with-scala-part-1/) recently, albeit in a different language. (see bullet 4)

Comment: Ah, ok. This snippet is fully functional. I just want to make sure my method is a generally accepted way of doing it.

Comment: Hi Marv, you can take a look at my example code for you. If you are gonna collect input many times, you can display input constraints once at the beginning or warning the user every time. It is a good alternative to catching exceptions. With this technique you are able to force users obey your input constraints as well, for instance it can be used for controlling a text field that is desired to accept just a particular string/numerical pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of throwing exceptions according to the input, keep your restrictions on the user input by getting use of the regular expressions. Java regular expressions will help you at this point.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Sample
{
    private final static Pattern DIGITS = Pattern.compile( "\\d*" );

    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        while ( true )
        {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if ( evalInput( input ) )
                process( input );
            else
                System.out.println("Input constraints: it must be just numerical.");
        }
    }

    public static void process ( String str )
    {
        // Whatever you wanna do with the accepted input.
    }

    public static boolean evalInput ( String str )
    {
        if ( str != null && DIGITS.matcher( str ).matches() )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Dang. Dedication. This helps a great deal!

Comment: I hope it helps a lot. You can check for the samples of the Java Regex and Pattern for complex or more specific inputs.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it just like you did, perhaps adding a prompt to re-enter.

```
while(true) {
  try {
    String s = read.nextLine();
    i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    break;
  } catch(NumberFormatException) {
    System.out.println("Please try again.");
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a particular reason why a while loop is preferred over a for loop?

Comment: Not really. Both `while(true)` and `for(;;)` look equally readable to me, though I prefer the former.

Comment: @Marv: beacuse it is more readable than for loop. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference.

Comment: Then why do forever loops exist? Shouldn't a while (true) loop suffice?

Comment: @Marv, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I meant forever loops as for(;;) loops. If while (true) can be used, why is for(;;) necessary?

Comment: @Marv, they're just two ways of doing the same thing. Use the one you like better.

Comment: @Marv, please make up your mind on one answer. Don't keep moving green arrow here and there.

Comment: @missingfaktor It's just that I like both answers. And both helped me equally.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd rather put the whole try-block inside the loop. I think it's easier to read than breaking out of try:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, I fin it clearer to write `while (true)` for an infinite loop, and wouldn't normaly use exceptions to handle user input.