# How do you use for(;;) loop

Tags: c, for-loop

This is a basic question but I've never really encountered this type of for loop before `for(;;)` .

How do you use this type of loop?
Do you simply break from it by calling `break;`?

I think this is a simple question but I can't find a solution online for it.

Comment: The best solution in such cases to write a couple of lines of code to try it.

Answer (score 3):

This is just one of the ways to run the loop infinitely. There's no initial condition, no terminating condition, the loop runs forever, unless you `break` it.

And if your next question arises which out of the two `while(1)` or `for(;;)` is better (performace/speed): [while (1) Vs. for (;;) Is there a speed difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference)

Answer (score 2):

A `for(;;)` loop is the same as `while(true)`. Any compiler will compile both as the same.

Answer (score 1):

This for loop is commonly the source of an infinite loop since the fundamental steps of iteration are completely in the control of the programmer. In fact, when infinite loops are intended, this type of for loop can be used (with empty expressions), such as:

```
for (;;)
   //loop body
```

You can break out of it. This is similar to an infinite while loop

```
while(1) 
   //loop body
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you break, or call a non-returning function such as `exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `for(;;)` is simply an infinite loop, Just like the `While(true)` loop.

and you can use the `Break;` to stop the loop or if you're using it in a return function.

```
for(;;){
  if(condition){
        break;
  }else {
    //do something
   } 
}
```

or

```
 int function(){
         for(;;){
           if(condition){
            return 0 ;
            }else {
        //do something
       }
    return 0 ; 
    }
```