# avr-gcc never returning main optimalization

Tags: c, gcc, avr

Somewhere I read that if I never return from `main()` loop, I can spare **~66** Bytes with some compiler switch in `avr-gcc`, but I couldn't find the site anymore.

This is for embedded:

```
main() {
 while(1)
 {
   // do stuff
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `gcc` you can use a special attribute to indicate that your function does not return:

```
int main() __attribute__ ((noreturn)) {
    for (;;) {
         // do stuff
    }
    __builtin_unreachable ();
}
```

Optionally you can add `__builtin_unreachable ();` to indicate that some part of the code can never be reached.

Although in most cases properly recognised by optimisation flags, without such `while(1)` can generate more code than `for(;;)`.

Comment: I was hopping for a non-compiler specific code part (like a comp. flag), but it will do, thanks!

Comment: Interesting while(1) vs for(;;) turns out to be the same asm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference

Answer (score 0):

I think these post are what you are looking for:
[AVR Freaks: main and `__attribute__ ((noreturn))`](https://www.avrfreaks.net/s/topic/a5C3l000000UB2jEAG/t056247)
[AVR Freaks: can't get `noreturn` attribute to work](https://www.avrfreaks.net/s/topic/a5C3l000000UMS0EAO/t100094)

Comment: [Sergey L](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1700513/sergey-l) just pinned an exact point You're linking to. Bare URL isn't the best possible answer ;}

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
If you are sure your main routine will never exit, you can use the "-mendup-at=main" flag when compiling. This will save 6 bytes of ROM.