# Why infinite for loop not while True in Python Interpreter OPCODE?

Tags: python, cpython

I have just started learning python, so it may seem a foolish question but i really want to know what could be the real possibility of not using the `while true` for the python interpreter which Execute compiled code with the help of [`ceval.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c) instead of `for (;;)` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L1221) in the same code.

I know the interpreter must go in infinite loop until something is returned hence the infinite for loop was written like this

```c
 for (;;) {
#ifdef WITH_TSC
        if (inst1 == 0) {
```

But going by the python own Principle **Readability counts** won't `while true` would have been a better option ?

Or this will have any performance difference ?

Comment: C didn't have `true`; it'd be `while (1)`. Back in the days `for (;;)` could have been faster and it has stuck. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala [while (1) Vs. for (;;) Is there a speed difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/887298/4532996) would seem to say... no, there isn't

Answer (score 1):

```
for (;;) {
```

is the classical way to make a C forever loop, stemming from the 1970's. I believe it's even in the original Kernighan and Ritchie book. It's idiomatic and a habit, there's no performance reason.

But strange enough most C programmers from that time would have written

```
if (!inst1) {
```

rather than

```
if (inst1 == 0) {
```

which makes this code a bit inconsistent stylewise...