# Why does calling a function in the Node.js REPL with )( work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

Why is it possible to call function in JavaScript like this, tested with node.js:

```
~$ node
> function hi() { console.log("Hello, World!"); };
undefined
> hi
[Function: hi]
> hi()
Hello, World!
undefined
> hi)( // WTF?
Hello, World!
undefined
>
```

Why does the last call, `hi)(`, work? Is it bug in node.js, bug in V8 engine, officially undefined behaviour, or actually valid JavaScript for all interpreters?

Comment: reproducible in nodejs v0.6.19 on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Not working with arguments :-)  http://i.stack.imgur.com/jyQwu.png

Comment: doesnt seem to do this in webkit, might be a node specific parser bug (http://jsfiddle.net/hxqrW/)

Comment: Reproducible in node v0.10.20 in Ubuntu 13.04, but not when executed from sublime

Comment: a quick test on jsfiddle.net will show you that it is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: Seems to be a Node REPL bug, putting the two lines in a `.js` will cause syntax error

Comment: @leesei Well, I was hoping this would be more interesting... Oh well, that seems to be the most accurate answer yet, so if you wanna write that as an answer, we can wrap this up with accepted answer.

Comment: Btw, credit where it is due, this came up at irc (FreeNode #nodejs), by @miniml

Comment: @Royi Did you try putting the arguments outside the asylum? =)

Comment: Perl has something similar for much the same reason: `perl -ne '$x += $_; }{ print $x'`. See [Hidden features of Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/162085/41861)

Comment: A better tag name would be, say, `[unexpected-behavior]`.  However, that would *also* be a meta tag.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Seems to be a Node REPL bug, putting these two lines in a `.js` will cause syntax error.

```
function hi() { console.log("Hello, World!"); }
hi)(
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Issue submitted [#6634](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6334).

Reproduced on v0.10.20.

---

v0.11.7 have this fixed.

```
$ nvm run 0.11.7
Running node v0.11.7
> function hi() { console.log("Hello, World!"); }
undefined
>  hi)(
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:44:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:117:23)
    at REPLServer.b [as eval] (domain.js:251:18)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:277:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:103:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:194:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:523:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:798:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:98:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
>
```

Comment: They actually went ahead and fixed it? Awwww, pity, I'd really like to see it start a culture and become a _feature_ in all languages. How many times have I typed )( instead of () in a hurry... :))

Comment: @geomagas You think `function a)arg1, arg2( } ]arg2 + arg1[ return; {` should be valid syntax?

Comment: No, not really. Actually, that was a joke.

Comment: Once upon a time there was a Lisp implementation with a DWIM option that automatically corrected misspellings and other minor errors. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM

Comment: @leesei Worth noting is that you don't need the trailing `;` after a function declaration, unless you're defining the function anonymously and assigning it to a variable (in which case it is **not** a function declaration - it is a statement). I've updated your answer to reflect as much.

Comment: @orokusaki yes, my linter also told me. I C&P'ed from the OP.

Comment: @geomagas, well, some have already went ahead and thought about it - `npm` has `install` **and** `isntall`. bet you haven't noticed :)

Comment: @EliranMalka well, after that, I bet we can ask ourselves, isn't all already invented? *runs away*

Answer (score 201):

It's due to how the REPL evaluates the input, which is ultimately as:

```
(hi)()
```

The additional parenthesis are added [to force it to be an *Expression*](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.20/lib/repl.js#L237-L239):

```
  // First we attempt to eval as expression with parens.
  // This catches '{a : 1}' properly.
  self.eval('(' + evalCmd + ')',
      // ...
```

The intent is to treat `{...}` as `Object` literals/[initialisers](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5) rather than as a [block](http://es5.github.io/#x12.1).

```
var stmt = '{ "foo": "bar" }';
var expr = '(' + stmt + ')';

console.log(eval(expr)); // Object {foo: "bar"}
console.log(eval(stmt)); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

And, as leesei mentioned, this has been changed for 0.11.x, which [will just wrap `{ ... }`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.7/lib/repl.js#L263-L274) rather than all input:

```
  if (/^\s*\{/.test(evalCmd) && /\}\s*$/.test(evalCmd)) {
    // It's confusing for `{ a : 1 }` to be interpreted as a block
    // statement rather than an object literal.  So, we first try
    // to wrap it in parentheses, so that it will be interpreted as
    // an expression.
    evalCmd = '(' + evalCmd + ')\n';
  } else {
    // otherwise we just append a \n so that it will be either
    // terminated, or continued onto the next expression if it's an
    // unexpected end of input.
    evalCmd = evalCmd + '\n';
  }
```

Comment: Does that mean that `hi)(arg` will work?  That could be abused to write some truly WTF-ridden code ;-)

Comment: I still don't understand why that would run. Wouldn't it make a syntax error because of the unmatched open paren?

Comment: `hi)(arg` becomes `(hi)(arg)` -- nothing unmatched

Answer (score 60):

There was a bug raised 4 months back, for this issue https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5698

And the problem was because, REPL encloses the statements with parens. So

```
foo)(
```

becomes

```
(foo)()
```

Actual explanation can be found here https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5698#issuecomment-19487718.

Comment: And I thought automatic semicolon insertion was bad.