# Merge pdf files with numerical sort

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, pdf, numeric

I am trying to write a bash script to merge all pdf files of a directory into one single pdf file. The command `pdfunite *.pdf output.pdf` successfully achieves this but it merges the input documents in a regular order:

```
1.pdf
10.pdf
11.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf
4.pdf
5.pdf
6.pdf
7.pdf
8.pdf
9.pdf
```

while I'd like the documents to be merged in a numerical order:

```
1.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf
4.pdf
5.pdf
6.pdf
7.pdf
8.pdf
9.pdf
10.pdf
11.pdf
```

I guess a command mixing `ls -v` or `sort -n` and `pdfunite` would do the trick but I don't know how to combine them.
Any idea on how I could merge pdf files **with a numerical sort?**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you can embed the result of command using `$()`,
so you can do following

```
$ pdfunite $(ls -v *.pdf) output.pdf
```

or

```
$ pdfunite $(ls *.pdf | sort -n) output.pdf
```

However, note that this does not work when filename contains special character such as whitespace.

In the case you can do the following:

```
ls -v *.pdf | bash -c 'IFS=$'"'"'\n'"'"' read -d "" -ra x;pdfunite "${x[@]}" output.pdf'
```

Although it seems a little bit complicated, its just combination of

- [Read tab-separated file line into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736202/bash-read-file-line-into-array)
- [build argument lists containing whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411495/build-argument-lists-containing-whitespace)
- [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/escaping-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Note that you cannot use `xargs` since `pdfunite` requires input pdf's as the middle of arguments.
I avoided using `readarray` since it is not supported in older bash version, but you can use it  instead of `IFS=.. read -ra ..` if you have newer `bash`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I confirm solution 1 & 2 work but I couldn't get solution 3 (xargs) to work. I think pdfunite is not recognizing the inputs. Could you explain your solution 3 in details?

Comment: sorry `xargs -I {}` only can apply argument one by one. forget it, I would write new answer.

Comment: Yes, that answer is actually a little bit wrong (second `sh` string is garbage) , so I updated the answer and wrote the correct one

Comment: Sorry again, I'm fool. I forgot to sort. `find` cannot sort. I would update answer again.

Comment: finally seems to got a working answer. hope this will be the final version.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time ymonad! I wouldn't have never figure it out by myself. Just on thing about your final command `ls -v *.txt | bash -c 'IFS=$'"'"'\n'"'"' read -d "" -ra x;pdfunite "${x[@]}" output.pdf'` you need to replace *.txt by *.pdf

Comment: @ymonad Can tihs case be extended to the numerical order and modified time order? Thread here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332348/16920

Comment: Try `sort -V` instead.

Comment: Note that if you're trying to merge many files (I was attempting to merge > 2k files), you may get bash "argument list too long" errors. I posted a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44528538/426790) that uses Python to iterate over a directory's PDFs files in "natural order" and merge them into one file.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the last command for numerical sorted should be `ls *.pdf |sort -n| bash -c 'IFS=$'"'"'\n'"'"' read -d "" -ra x;pdfunite "${x[@]}" output.pdf'`. The `ls -v` option doesn't work for 1 vs 10.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
destfile=combined.pdf
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 \
   | sort -z -t '/' -k2n \
   | { cat; printf '%s\0' "$destfile"; } \
   | xargs -0 -x pdfunite
```

1. Variable `destfile` holds the name of the destination pdf file.
2. The `find` command finds all the pdf files in the current directory and outputs them as a NUL delimited list.
3. The `sort` command reads the NUL delimited list of filenames. It specifies a field delimiter of `/`. It sorts by the 2nd field numerically. (Recall that the output of `find` looks like `./11.pdf ...`.)
4. We append `destfile` before sending to `xargs`, being sure to end it with a NUL.
5. xargs reads the NUL delimited args and supplies them to the `pdfunite` command. We supplied the `-x` option so that `xargs` will exit if the command length is too long. We don't want `xargs` to execute a partially constructed command.

This solution handles filenames with embedded newlines and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in multiple steps. I am assuming you have files from 1 to 99.

```
 pdfunite $(find ./ -regex ".*[^0-9][0-9][^0-9].*"  | sort) out1.pdf
 pdfunite out1.pdf $(find ./ -regex ".*[^0-9]1[0-9][^0-9].*"  | sort) out2.pdf
 pdfunite out2.pdf $(find ./ -regex ".*[^0-9]2[0-9][^0-9].*"  | sort) out3.pdf
```

and so on.

the final file will consist of all your pdfs in numerical order.

!!!
Beware of writing the output file such as out1.pdf etc. otherwise pdfunite will overwrite the last file 
!!!

Edit: 
Sorry I was missing the [^0-9] in each regex. Corrected it in the above commands.

Comment: thanks for the tip but it doesn't sort correctly. If you merge `1.pdf, 2.pdf, 11.pdf`, the order will be `11.pdf, 1.pdf, 2.pdf`. Changing `sort` to `sort -n` doesn't fix the problem

Comment: thanks and I corrected the answer. Also, want to say that the command above is not generic, but covers most of the human genreated files.

Comment: thanks for this correction but it doesn't work yet. `pdfunite $(find ./ -regex ".*[^0-9][0-9][^0-9].*"  | sort) out1.pdf` generates `out1.pdf` that includes 1.pdf and 2.pdf only (not 11.pdf)

Comment: you have to follow other commands as well. Run the next line and you will get 11.pdf. If you see carefully, in the second line the input is out1.pdf and the output is out2.pdf. Even the regex is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your documents i.e. 001.pdf 002.pdf and so on.