# Unix commandline history substitution ^foo^bar (for multiple replacements)

Tags: bash, unix, history

Occasionally I use the bash command to replace string in previous command:

```
^foo^bar
```

Today I wanted to make the replacement in the following line for replacing all occurrences of `checkbox` with `radio:

```
$ git mv _product_checkbox_buttons.html.erb _product_checkbox_button.html.erb
$ ^checkbox^radio
git mv _product_radio_buttons.html.erb _product_checkbox_button.html.erb
```

So it only replaces the first occurrence. How do I make it replace all occurrences?

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`man bash` says `^old^new` is equivalent to `!!:s/old/new/`. You want `!!:gs/old/new/` to globally replace.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
AT this point, bash commands suddenly appear very ugly and non-readable. But it's amazing what you can do !

Comment: I agree! That g definitely belongs at the end!

Comment: Yeah, I pretty sure you want !!:s/old/new/g, so in the case of the original questioner, you want !!:s/checkbox/radio/g

Comment: @Jim, yeah that's how it should work, but it doesn't. Bash history demands the g at the start, not at the end. Putting it at the end will do a single substitution only, followed by a literal "g". Try it.

Comment: @jesper, you are trying to use the c-shell based syntax. maybe have a look at the vi or emacs command line editing interface. much more powerful.

Answer (score 14):

An easy way of doing this would be:

```
fc -s checkbox=radio
```

I have an alias `r` defined in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias r='fc -s'
```

Then what you want to do becomes:

```
r checkbox=radio
```

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211378/hidden-features-of-bash/1881903#1881903) to "[hidden features of bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211378)" question for details.

Comment: This should be **the** answer, as it is so easy to remember and otherwise I have google every time I need to do this.

Comment: I like this over `^foo^bar^` and `!!:gs/foo/bar/` because I can easily put this into an alias. I frequently want to run a modified version of a command, not just fix a typo, and this makes the process smoother