# How do I keep a Perl script running on Unix after I log off?

Tags: scheduling, nohup, keep-alive, at-job

I have a script that takes a lot of time to complete.

Instead of waiting for it to finish, I'd rather just log out and retrieve its output later on.

I've tried;

`at -m -t 03030205 -f /path/to/./thescript.pl`

`nohup /path/to/./thescript.pl &`

And I have also verified that the processes actually exist with `ps` and `at -l` depending on which scheduling syntax i used.

Both these processes die when I exit out of the shell.  Is there a way to keep a script from terminating when I close the connection?

We have crons here and they are set up and are working properly, but I would like to use `at` or `nohup` for single-use scripts.

Is there something wrong with my syntax?  Are there any other methods to producing the desired outcome?

---

**EDIT:**
I cannot use `screen` or `disown` - they aren't installed in my HP Unix setup and i am not in the position to install them either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a guess, but something I've seen with some versions of ssh and nohup: if you've logged in with ssh then you may need to need to redirect stdout, stderr **and** stdin to avoid having the session hang when you exit.  (One of those may still be attached to the terminal.)  I would try:

```
nohup /path/to/./thescript.pl > whatever.stdout 2> whatever.stderr < /dev/null &
```

(This is no longer the case with my current versions of ssh and nohup - the latter redirects them if it detects that any is attached to a terminal - but you may be using different versions.)

Comment: thanks for the info mark... the script directs all output into a `.csv` file.  i don't know if i need to redirect to stdout

Comment: actually im going to rewrite the print statements so they print to the screen and then try your suggestion

Comment: nice! its autonomous, just the way i like it.... i just hope it doesn't become self-aware

Answer (score 12):

Use [screen](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=unix+screen). It creates a terminal which keeps going when you log out.  When you log back in you can switch back to it.

Comment: You can't go wrong with screen. Take a few minutes to learn and get familiar with it.  It will be worth your time down the line.

Comment: GNU `screen` is awesome for lots of reasons, including this. Definitely recommend it.

Comment: i dont think i have screen - theres no man doc for it and im in no position to install it unless it could be done on a local level.  thanks for the reading material though

Answer (score 5):

[**If you want to keep a process running after you log out:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211378/hidden-features-of-bash/585666#585666)

`disown -h <pid>`

is a useful bash built-in. Unlike `nohup`, you can run `disown` on an already-running process.

First, stop your job with control-Z, get the pid from `ps` (or use `echo $!`), use `bg` to send it to the background, then use `disown` with the -h flag.

Don't forget to background your job or it will be killed when you logout.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for nohup looks ok, but your account may not allow for processes to run after logout. Also, try redirecting the stdout/stderr to a log file or /dev/null.

Comment: thanks for the info... the script, by nature, directs all output to a `.csv` file so its not that important (as far as i know) to redirect to anything else

Answer (score 1):

Run your command in background.

```
/path/to/./thescript.pl &
```

To get lits of your background jobs

```
   jobs
```

Now you can selectively disown any of the above jobs, with its jobid.

```
disown <jobid>
```

All the disowned process should be keep on running even after you logged out.

Comment: definitely helpful, but is there any other ways to "disown" the process?