# Submit jobs to run in background using Perl

Tags: perl

i have a perl script where i am submitting a hadoop command to run in background, in the while loop for each record in a another input file. My scenario is , i have to fire the hadoop commands to unix and make it run background, DO NOT WAIT for the background process to finish and go to the next record in the input file and fire the next one.
The code which is below submits the hadoop command in background , but it waits for it complete which i dont want to.

```
open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$data>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @fields = split "," , $line;
  if( $fields[7] == 'Y' ) {
`nohup sqoop export
--connect
"jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver:1433;database=$fields[0];user=sa;password=pwd"
--table $fields[2]
--export-dir $src_dir
--input-fields-terminated-by '$fields[3]'
--input-lines-terminated-by '$fields[4]'
--m $fields[5]
--staging-table $fields[6]
--clear-staging-table
--batch > $tgt_dir/$fields[2].out & `;
echo $! > $pid_file;
} 
else {
   next;
}
}
```

Please let me know how can i do it..

Also,The hadoop command can run for more than few minutes. I have to make the script wait for background commands ,with the help of pid, which were fired  and give a report based on the STDOUT files by hadoop commands.

Need help on how to accomplish this....

Comment: There are many, many questions on background processes in Perl, and help available elsewhere on the web, too.  You need to put more effort into this before asking here.

Comment: `GNU Parallel` Might interests you, https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/; which is written in perl. It does your job quickly without even writing complex programs to manage jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `nohup [command] &` inside perl isn't working as you intended. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190806/how-do-i-keep-a-perl-script-running-on-unix-after-i-log-off) (something to do with stdout. also your echo should be inside the backticks).

For example:

```
perl -E 'say `nohup sleep 30 & echo \$! > foo.pid &`'
```

does not run in the background for me.

But:

```
perl -E 'say `nohup sleep 30 > /dev/null & echo \$! > foo.pid`'
```

Will work. Having said that the comments saying you should google more about background processes in perl are warranted. Specifically using fork() (or some cpan module using it) and then managing your child processes from there.

Comment: Parallel::ForkManager is the gold standard of child-process-herders.