# What are good places to find free XAML images?

Tags: wpf, xaml

As I started using WPF at higher DPI resolutions, I got into troubles with scaling of toolbar images. XAML images solve that problem.

However I find it very hard to find free toolbar/ribbon XAML images that you can use in your own projects. What I found is usually not free and one probably needs more than few collections to get all needed images.

Where do you find your toolbar/ribbon .xaml images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following link
[Hidden features of WPF and XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124769/hidden-features-of-wpf-and-xaml/1405000#1405000)

There is a list of converters that can take many formats of images and convert them to xaml for you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wind up using [InkScape](http://www.inkscape.org/) to create my XAML a lot.  Even with my meager drawing skills, it's fairly easy to use and very effective.

As a note, though, I tend to work with the image in the native format and then save as XAML.  Working with a file in XAML format seems to be somewhat unstable.