# Binding errors not showing on output window

Tags: wpf, binding

My output window does not show binding errors for my project. However on a colleagues machine, binding errors are displayed in the output window.

Any ideas on how to switch this on on my machine (the source code is identical on both machines so I'm guessing it is an IDE setting).

Comment: Are your running the application in Release mode, by any chance?

Answer (score 20):

Try

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> WPF Trace Settings
>   -> Data Binding

Comment: If if I set to Error or Warning, I still see nothing, while my colleague sees errors on same settings with same source?

Comment: That didn't work for me either, but I'm using a different machine now, so it works in there.

Comment: Use `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> WPF Trace Settings -> Data Binding->All`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and making the appropriate changes (Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> WPF Trace Settings -> Data Binding), I still couldn't see any DataBinding issues in the Output window. The problem was I found this line in my App.cs code

```
System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.Critical;
```

This option was obviously overwriting the settings I made in the Options menu.

Comment: This happened again to me again. Wish I could up vote more than once.

Comment: where is the app.cs file? you meant app.XAML.cs?

Answer (score 3):

If the following solution doesn't work for you:

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> WPF Trace Settings -> Data Binding

Try to right click on the Output area of the Output Window, and Select all output messages you want, and especially Program Output option.

[image: All output messages]

Answer (score 2):

In some settings configurations, first-chance exception notifications are displayed in the Immediate window.

To toggle first-chance exception notifications in the Immediate window On the View menu, click Other Windows, and click Output.

Right-click on the text area of the Output window, and select or deselect Exception Messages.