# WPF trace information not shown in output window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, trace

I followed the steps listed here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx

Which is modifying the settings in `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> WPF Trace Settings`

However changing these settings did not add any trace info to the output window. I even tried using `PresentationTraceSources` but it didn't help. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Answer (score 0):

Check out XMight's answer for [Binding errors not showing on output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850143/binding-errors-not-showing-on-output-window), to see if it helps you to see the output you are expecting.

Comment: All of the message types are checked there