# WPF binding errors not showing up anywhere no matter what I do

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, data-binding

I used to be able to see when there were binding errors at runtime or compile time in the output window.  Now they're never there.  I've seen things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850143/binding-errors-not-showing-on-output-window) and tried all the answers, and nothing is showing in the intermediate window either.

Here's a simple test.  I created a WPF app and just added a text box to the main window, then I set the binding on the `Text` property to a non-existent binding source `blah`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
            Margin="151,91,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="{Binding blah}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm able to run the app just fine (which I know is typical because binding errors are usually swallowed, i.e. they don't result in an exception), but I thought the errors were supposed to be in the output window.  Nothing.

What is going on?

Comment: what have you selected at "show output from: " ?

Comment: "Debug"..........

Comment: Can you try to enable extensive tracing for that specific binding with diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"  (diag beeing  xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"). This is of course not a general solution.

Comment: Ok, I did that, but still no output.

Comment: weird. Out of ideas here. If all the answers in the other question did not work for you the only thing i could think of would be reinstalling VS...

Comment: Well thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Sorry to be captain obvious, but I assume you rebooted your computer and restarted VS?

Comment: Restarted VS a number of times, and rebooted, yes.  No help there.

Comment: I just fired up VS2013 and I too get nothing... If I use VS2015, the output is there. In VS2013, if I override OnStartup in app.xaml.cs and manually add a ConsoleTraceListener to System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources then I get output.

Comment: using System.Diagnostics; PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener()); PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;

Comment: Actually, just setting the switch level seems to show output. Adding the listener isn't even needed.

Comment: I did just find something that seems to 'fix' it... Tools->Options->Debugging->General and checking "Use Managed Compatibility Mode". Make sure Debugging->Output Window has Data Binding set to All (or Information since that is what your binding error is logged as).

Comment: Worked for me, too.  Weird: [this MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/) post says there are only two scenarios where I'd need to use this feature, and neither of them relate to this problem.  I'm reluctant to keep that setting on because I don't want to lose the fancy new features that the legacy debugger prevents.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't add it as an answer - more of a Band-Aid than a good answer/fix. It seems to be something with the switch level not being set since it does show if you manually set it in code at startup. Maybe try researching that? IDK...

Comment: Strange thing is: I *know* I've seen the errors in the Output window before, and while using VS 2013.  Something must have changed in my environment.