# Use Window DataContext in child element after overriding DataContext in parent

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've got a viewmodel that contains a collection of objects and a bunch of commands.

```
public class MainWindowVM : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private CollectionViewSource employeeViewSource;

    private ICommand cmdOpenDetailEmployee;

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        nsDataProviderEmployees = new NSDataProvider();

        employeeViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();

        cmdOpenDetailEmployee = new RelayCommand<object>((parameter) => {...});

        this.LoadData();
    }

    public CollectionViewSource EmployeeViewSource => employeeViewSource;
    public ICommand CmdOpenDetailEmployee => cmdOpenDetailEmployee;
}
```

In my application I want to use this command in a context menu of the datagrid showing the employees.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.UI"
        xmlns:DataModel="clr-namespace:MyApp.DataModel;assembly=MyApp.DataModel" x:Class="MyApp.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.UI.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyApp - Main" Height="751.826" Width="1111.005" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Icon="Resources/MyApp.ico">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowVM />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid x:Name="grdMain">
        <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Path=EmployeeViewSource}" x:Name="employeeDataGrid" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,77,10,0" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                    <MenuItem Header="OpenDetail..."
                              Command="{Binding CmdOpenDetailEmployee}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <DataGrid.Columns>...</DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**The Problem is** I am unable to come up with a combination of bindings that both let me use the `EmployeeViewSource` property or my ViewModel as DataContext for the grid AND the `CmdOpenDetailEmployee` property of my ViewModel as the DataContext for my ContextMenu and MenuItems.

According to all the posts I've been able to find  this *should* work but the command isn't executed when I click the menu item.

Comment: First, see whether the problem is actually with the binding or with the command. Check if you can find binding errors (see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850143/binding-errors-not-showing-on-output-window). Also check in the debugger if the Execute method of your command is actually being invoked. From the question it is not really possible to tell more...

Comment: I retract the last sentence of my previous comment. :-) Come to think of it, it might be the binding using `FindAncestor`. Since the context menu is a popup window, it might not have the main window as an ancestor (i am not 100% sure here). The binding could very well just find the popup window element of the context menu (if there is such). Try using a binding with  `ElementName` instead (you would need to give your main window a name, of course), and see what happens...

Comment: @elgonzo Here's there error from the Output `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')` The execute method of my command isn't called. And I haven't managed to get a binding with ElementName to work either: `Command="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=CmdOpenDetailEmployee}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to the `DataContext` of the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu`, and let the `DataGrid` inherit its `DataContext` from the window:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="employeeDataGrid" 
        EnableRowVirtualization="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeViewSource.View}" Margin="10,77,10,0" 
        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="OpenDetail..."
                              Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.CmdOpenDetailEmployee, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <!--<DataGrid.Columns>...</DataGrid.Columns>-->
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: If I remove the DataContext from the DataGrid then I no longer get any data displayed...

Comment: Why are you defining a CollectionViewSource in the view model? Anyway, you could bind to EmployeeViewSource.View. See my edit.

Comment: Legacy code which I'm trying to move towards MVVM. I'm pretty new to this myself. What would be a better approach? --- Either way: If I remove the DataGrid DataContext and bind ItemsSource to the View the grid works and I can bind the MenuItem straight to the command with `{Binding CmdOpenDetailEmployee}` Thanks!