# Multibinding Converter not called in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

When `SelectedItem` value changes it does not trigger `SelectedItemConverter`.

I tried to use `SetCurrentValue` and `InvalidateProperty` and fiddled with attributes like
`NotifyOnSourceUpdated`, `UpdateSourceTrigger` and `Mode`.

Sadly they do not work.

Perhaps I should add something in parent xaml to nudge it?
Currently its:

```xml
   <local:Menu
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}"
            OnSelect="{Binding OnSelectCommand}" Items="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
```

Thanks for help.

**control xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:MockMenuViewModel x:Key="DesignViewModel"/>
        <cv:SelectedItemConverter x:Key="SelectedItemConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl
        d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DesignViewModel}}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                        Command="{Binding OnSelect, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <Button.IsEnabled>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemConverter}"
                                      NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"
                                      NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" Mode="OneWay">
                            <Binding Path="SelectedItem" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="OneWay"/>
                            <Binding Path="." Mode="OneWay"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Button.IsEnabled>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

**control cs**

```cs
 public partial class Menu : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedItem",
            typeof(MenuItem),
            typeof(Menu),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Items",
            typeof(IEnumerable<MenuItem>),
            typeof(Menu),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OnSelectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "OnSelect",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(Menu),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectChanged));


        public MenuItem SelectedItem
        {
            get => (MenuItem)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Items)));
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<MenuItem> Items
        {
            get => (IEnumerable<MenuItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
        }

        public ICommand OnSelect
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(OnSelectProperty);
            set => SetValue(OnSelectProperty, value);
        }

        public static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var menu = dependencyObject as Menu;

            if (menu == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            menu.InvalidateProperty(SelectedItemProperty);
            menu.InvalidateProperty(ItemsProperty);
        }

        public static void OnSelectChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var menu = dependencyObject as Menu;

            if (menu == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            menu.SetCurrentValue(OnSelectProperty, eventArgs.NewValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't `Path="SelectedItem"` points to `MenuItem.SelectedItem` and not `Menu.SelectedItem` ... remeber ... you are inside `DataTemplate`

Comment: I thought it would try to find property on collection item and if theres nothing it would go up in hierarchy to user control. How to add RelativeSource here when Binding is a xml node, not attribute?

Comment: `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource ... to parent}" Path="prop in parent"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to bind to the `SelectedItem` property of the parent `Menu` `UserControl`, you should specify a `RelativeSource`:

```
<Binding Path="SelectedItem"
    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"
    UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="OneWay"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, whats really annoyed me here wpf does not tell you that "oh btw I could not find that property anywhere during binding". Is there something like strict mode?

Comment: You can [trace binding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850143/binding-errors-not-showing-on-output-window) but I am afraid there is no way to automatically validate them at compile time in WPF.