# Display multiline DynamicResource Label

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamicresource

I wish to add a Label in WPF that displays string from two different DynamicResources.
I want each DynamicResource to be on a new line.

My existing code is:

```
<Label x:Name="MyTextDisplay"  
       Grid.Row="3"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Background="Red"
       BorderBrush="Blue"
       BorderThickness="1"
       Margin="2, 2, 2, 2">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{DynamicResource MyTextLine1}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</Label>
```

I have another DynamicResource called MyTextLine2 that I want to display below MyTextLine1 but in the same Label.

How can I do this?

I have looked at these examples here but they dont display on new lines: [How to bind multiple values to a single WPF TextBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552853/how-to-bind-multiple-values-to-a-single-wpf-textblock)

Comment: try changing the Label's datatemplate. Have a grid or a stackpanel and that should do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409587/how-is-it-possible-to-stuff-a-grid-inside-a-textblock

Comment: Use a `StackPanel` inside `Label`and put your `TextBlocks` in that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and finally I found a solution.
Just use \r\n linebreak instead of just \n.
So, your resourse must look like:

```
 <system:String x:Key="MyText" xml:space="preserve">Line 1&#10;&#13;Line 2</system:String>
```

I realy don't know why this notation must be used only for dynamic resources, but it works for me