# Model property change notifications

Tags: wpf, data-binding, properties, model, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the binding update without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767218/why-does-the-binding-update-without-implementing-inotifypropertychanged)

I have WPF:

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SomeProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Bound to

```
class MyModel1
{
    string _someProperty = string.Empty;
    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty; }
        set { _someProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

It allso works with:

```
    class MyModel
        {
            public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
        }
```

As You see there is no Property Change notifications, but TextBlock is updated while i am typing to TextBox. 
I am using Visual C# express 2010, standard WPF app project template, standard contols, no snippets, nothing additional, with .NET 4 client profile.

- Question 1: Why it works?
- Question 2: Is that new feature of .NET 4?
- Question 3: How I could get notifications about property changes from
  my code without implementing any events in my model?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 if that's work,  WPF's data binding engine will data bind to `PropertyDescriptor` instance which wraps the source property if the source object is a plain CLR object and doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

`PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged()` method permit to subscribe to notification.

The change is not synchronized as desired, we use `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to customize this aspect.

2 You can read this article it's interessant

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx

Comment: Thank You very much. With Your supplied keyword I found that this thing was allready discussed here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767218/why-does-the-binding-update-without-implementing-inotifypropertychanged)

Comment: I'am happy to help you Dule, if you have another question i tried to help