# Can bindings work to source properties that don't implement Inotifypropertychanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class that implements Inotifypropertychanged. I also have this property that I commented out the notification on.

```
private Color _CoolColor =Colors.Purple;
    public Color CoolColor
    {
      get
      {
        return _CoolColor;
      }
      set
      {
        if (value != _CoolColor)
        {
          _CoolColor = (Color)value;
          //OnPropertyChanged("CoolColor");
        }
      }
    }
```

a binding in my xaml attaches to this property:

```
BusTextColor="{Binding Path=CoolColor}"

 /// <summary>
    /// Color used for the text containing the hex value of the bus
    /// </summary>
    public Color BusTextColor
    {
      get
      {
        return (Color)GetValue(BusTextColorProperty);
      }
      set
      {
        SetValue(BusTextColorProperty, value);
      }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BusTextColorProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("BusTextColor",
      typeof(Color), typeof(SignalGraph),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Color(), new PropertyChangedCallback(CreateBrushesAndReDraw)));
```

I only bound this cause I wanted to make sure that I wasn't crazy, but I must be crazy because my BusTextColor is updating when CoolColor changes.  Someone please make it stop working.

I was only doing this because another dependency property I have is not binding to my viewmodel properly. I know there is probably some obvious reason for this, but I'm definitely missing it.

edit:
that article was interesting. but in my case I have the Inotifypropertychanged interface implemented, I just don't raise the event OnPropertyChanged. I realized I should have posted that as well.

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
  PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null)
  {
    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }
}
```

Comment: Not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and not RAISING the event are 2 different things. which one are you talking about?

Comment: this may be related, don't know if it applies as you say you actually have the interface in the class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767218/why-does-the-binding-update-without-implementing-inotifypropertychanged

Comment: ah i mean not raising the event. doesn't the event have to get raised for the property change to propagate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one had an obvious answer, I knew I had done something wrong elsewhere and what I was posting should work.

Eventually realized it was a bug I had before. Somewhere I had changed the value of the target manually and broke the binding. Need to start checking for code interference with the binding in these situations rather than assuming I am using incorrect syntax for the binding in xaml

Answer (score 1):

> Someone please make it stop working.

Just set the `BindingMode` to `OneTime`