# MVVM with complex Models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

When utilising the MVVM pattern I am coming into some trouble when the `Model` objects become complex, that is, when they contain Properties which are non-primitive / not built-in. In my particular instance I have a `ModelA` which contains a collection of `ModelB` objects which themselves contains a collection of `ModelC` objects:

```
class ModelA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OberservableCollection<ModelB> Bs { get; set; }
}

class ModelB
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ModelC> Cs { get; set; }
}

class ModelC
{
    public string Brand{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a `ModelAViewModel` which permits access to the collection of `ModelB Bs` property. In this instance I have not created a `ViewModel` for `ModelB`. I have styled the `ModelB` and `ModelC` collections (and individual instances) by using `DataTemplate`s:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="modelATemplate">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Bs}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource modelBTemplate}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="modelBTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Make}">
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Cs}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=modelCTemplate}">
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have been advised that this is not the MVVM way of doing things and that each entity, that is, `ModelB` and `ModelC` should have their own `ViewModel`. I have been told to keep the `Model` classes but create `ViewModel`s for them. I am unable to visualise how this is going to work.

If I create a `ModelBViewModel`:

```
public class ModelBViewModel
{
     ModelB MyModelB { get; set; }
}
```

I have a predicament - I already have `ModelB` instances within the `ModelA` class, I would now have other `ModelB` instances in the `ModelBViewModel`. Is it necessary to iterate through the original `ModelB` collection within `ModelA` and create the `ModelBViewModel`s, setting the `MyModelB` property to match that in `ModelA` as I go? It seems a bit complicated for what should be rather simple?

Comment: Your models are using `ObservableCollection` (to rise notification), but you didn't implement notification of any kind for e.g. `ModelB.Make`, `ModelB.Cs` and `ModelC.Brand` changes. So while technically you display them it's not MVVM. Typically models have to provide a mechanism to inform ViewModel (`INotifyPropertyChanged` is good), while ViewModels nearly `must` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Probably the easier is to make `ModelB`/`ModelC` implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then they are actually become ViewModels which can be used directly for bindings.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7767218/1997232) for why binding to something not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` is working. TLDR; changes made to models will only be visible in the view if view itself made them.

Comment: @Sinatr Not raising a notification does not mean that "it's not MVVM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVVM means "Model View ViewModel". As you can see, the name contains Model and ViewModel. The idea is to have a dedicated ViewModel class for every Model class you have.

The ViewModel should contain view-specific properties and logic while the Model class should contain business model specfic properties and logic.

And: Yes, for some very simple MVVM examples this might be overhead. However you benefit from this seperation as soon as your view logic starts to diverge from your business logic.

If it is necessary to iterate through the original properties: I would say: Yes!
I usually do it this way:

```
public class ModelBViewModel
{
    private ModelB _model;

    public ObservableCollection<ModelCViewModel> CVms { get; set; }

    public ModelBViewModel(ModelB model) {
        _model = model;
        CVms = new ObservableCollection();
        foreach(var modelC in model.Cs) {
            CVms.Add(new ModelCViewModel(modelC));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Linq:  `CVms = new ObservableCollection(model.Cs.Select(c=> new ModelCViewModel(c)));`

Comment: I always thought that one should create a ViewModel for each View not for each Model. Otherwise what good does it provide besides MVC

Comment: Yes, you should create a view model for each view. However, when you want to display your model data in more than one view it can make it easier to reuse your view model code when you have a view model for each model.

Comment: @makzr do you possibly have a larger example that puts what you’ve written here in context? I have pretty much the *exact* same question as OP, and I also feel that manually iterating through the collection to create a VM for each model instance seems clunky next to, say, setting a data template and then just using a contentcontrol, which is so much more, like, “automatic”.