# View bound to non-INotifyPropertyChanged, still updating

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, viewmodel, inotifypropertychanged

I needed a trivial example of how `INotifyPropertyChanged` is useful, but my demo app is going totally against my expectations.

```
namespace WpfApp2CS
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
}


<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2CS"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="300" Height="150"
        x:Class="WpfApp2CS.MainWindow">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Value="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

I was under the impression that the setter of `Value` would be hit every time the slider moves, but the getter would only be hit once because `ViewModel` doesn't raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`. This is not the case; the text updates with every movement of the slider.

Comment: That's the power of XAML `DataBinding`, which causes the property in your example to stay in sync. If, however, the data is changed programmatically, the UI will not reflect the changes unless you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: The `TextBlock` isn't updating for me when I try your example. That's because when the slider updates `Value`, no notification is raised, and so the binding on `TextBlock.Text` is not aware that it needs to update its target. If it updates for you, I suspect you pasted the wrong code into your question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Works for me, I remember reading about this in [C# 6.0 and .NET 4.6](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484213339). After quick google search, also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767218/why-does-the-binding-update-without-implementing-inotifypropertychanged).

Comment: @Funk Wow, yes. I wasn't testing exactly the same thing after all, I just added a non-notifying property to a test viewmodel I had. It was I who had the wrong code! It works when I do it just as OP did. That is deeply weird.

Comment: Thanks @Funk! I had a feeling it was magic.

Comment: Always glad to enlighten :)