# Listview doesn't get updated when selected property changes in code

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a simple demo application which shows a list and edit box shows the selected property. If I change the property in edit boxes, the list gets updated. But if I modify the same in code (cmmand handler) it doesn't get updated. Why is that?

```
<StackPanel>
        <ListView  Margin="10" Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Content="Update" Command="{Binding CmdUpdate}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

My ViewModel class is here

```
   class SimpleListViewModel : Notifier
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;
        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
        {
            get
            {
                return _persons;
            }
            set
            {
                _persons = value; // 
                OnPropertyChanged("Persons");
            }
        }

        private Person _selectedPerson;

        public Person SelectedPerson
        {
            get { return _selectedPerson; }
            set 
            { 
                _selectedPerson = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
            }
        }


        public RelayCommand CmdUpdate { get; private set; }

        public SimpleListViewModel()
        {
            var albert = new Person() { FirstName = "Albert", LastName = "Einstein" };
            var bruno = new Person() { FirstName = "Bruno", LastName = "Latour" };
            var charles = new Person() { FirstName = "Charles", LastName = "Darwin" };
            var newton = new Person() { FirstName = "Isaac", LastName = "Newton" };
            var hawking = new Person() { FirstName = "Stephen", LastName = "Hawking" };

            _persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>() { albert, bruno, charles, newton, hawking };

            CmdUpdate = new RelayCommand(OnCmdUpdate, IsCmdUpdateEnabled);
        }

        private bool IsCmdUpdateEnabled(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void OnCmdUpdate(object obj)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(SelectedPerson.FirstName);
            SelectedPerson.FirstName += " CHANGED"; // listview NOT getting updated
        }
    };
```

Comment: Probably because you didn't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for FirstName and LastName.

Comment: @cfun that’s right but why does the binding with textbox work and it does update the list when FirstName is changed!

Comment: Searched it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7767218/1136211

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that when the data is updated via data binding and the `Binding.Source` is not a `DependencyProperty`, the binding engine will use reflection to to resolve the source property and then create a `ValueChanged` handler in case the `Binding.Source` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (which seems to be the true for `Person`). This will create a static reference to the source object, which is known to be a potential memory leak. The `TextBox.Text` property does all the work, since it is a `DependencyProperty` (remember that the `Binding.Target` *must* be a `DependencyProperty`). But if you omit the binding engine and manipulate the property directly and the class of this property doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and doesn't raise the `PropertyChanged` event, the bindings that reference this manipulated property won't get notified about the manipulation.

To solve this `Person` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the `Person.FirstName` property must raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChnaged` event.

It is highly recommended to implement properties of every `DependencyObject` that are either `Binding.Source` or `Binding.Target` as `DependencyProperty`. This will result in the best performance.
If the `Binding.Source` is not a `DependencyObject`, it must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If it doesn't, the performance impact will be significantly worse. See [Microsoft Docs: Optimizing Performance: Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-data-binding).