# Default Button content with data binding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

This may be something simple I'm missing. Is it possible to set Button content to binding while still showing some default text in designer?

Ex. `<Button Content="{Binding buttonContent}"/>`

Binding works properly, but in designer the button content is just blank. We would like it to show some text like "Start" in designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `FallbackValue`:

```
<Button Content="{Binding buttonContent, FallbackValue=Start}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `TargetNullValue`.

For your example it would look like this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding buttonContent, TargetNullValue=Start}"/>
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124769/hidden-features-of-wpf-and-xaml) may be useful to you as well.