# What is the basic principle of a core on framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

right now, i have to create a framework. and need to understand more about the concept behind it. so, is there any documentation about how to build core of a framework ?

or at least, what is your approach when you have to create one ?

btw, what i mean with core, is, the skeleton. the part of framework that works as controller who control the controllers.

for example, my personal question :
1. How we create easy to maintain and customize configs ?
2. How we load a class that have dependency with another class ?
3. How we treat our models ?
4. etc ?

@edited : the framework is would be a framework for wordpress theme.

i'm sorry if the question is too broad. but any reference will be great.

Comment: the part of framework that controls and coordinate initialization of models and views and controllers

Comment: For any kind of meaningful response, you will need to explain in a lot more detail what you are trying to do. Also explain what specific parts you have questions on. How do I architect and design a framework ? is not going to work. In it's current form I vote to close.

Comment: @Romain Hippeau - agreed, except to vote to close; this is still a valid question who's answer has more to do with inception and scoping than it does with writing frameworks.

Comment: Read through the CodeIgniter source code. It's about as good a PHP  framework as you're going to find.

Comment: @meager i have read codeigniter. frankly, my job is about porting previous codeigniter code and move it into wordpress. i have destroy it skeleton (configs) and build it again to work on wordpress as theme....may be it too broad question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

K, I usually tend to champion the [Not Invented Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here) mentality, [encouraging people to re-invent the wheel as a learning exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948323/how-to-increase-my-advanced-knowledge-of-php-further-quickly/3000160#3000160)... but the way you've asked this question suggests to me that you've decided to build a framework *before deciding why you want or need that framework*.

What do you *want* this framework to do? Equally, what do you *not* want it to do?

Once you've made that decision, read up on some [WebEA design patterns](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa) and decide what combination of patterns best suits your goals.

Asking "How do you write the core of a framework?" is like asking "How do you structure literature?" in that there's no real answer without knowing if you're talking about a novel or a play or a poem.