# How to increase your skill as a php developer

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increase my “advanced” knowledge of PHP further? (quickly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948323/how-to-increase-my-advanced-knowledge-of-php-further-quickly)

I have just finished learning the basics of PHP and MySQL and I need some kind of practical experience to improve my skill or some kind of professional job. Any idea how to do this and expand my knowledge as a PHP developer?

Comment: Not a very useful question.  Also reconsider the title.

Comment: you answered your own question - you want practical experience - so, got out and write code

Answer (score 2):

Work on open source projects or start your own. The benefits are countless, but specifically:

1. You'll work with more seasoned developers who may offer you advice
2. You'll have work you can show others that people actually use
3. You'll gain more experience with your tools

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

1. Offering your service on craig's
   list 'pro bono.'
2. Take a topic of interest to you and design a web site support it. For example, Let's say you like wine. Write a website and db that tracks wine, vintages, purchases, opinion,s etc.
3. Also I recommend the Heads First PHP book

Comment: +1 for Head First book advice.

Answer (score 1):

To get a professional job you gotta really be able to develop in PHP. Think about some problem and try to find a solution in PHP for it.

I don't know maybe start with a nice little todo list web-app. Try to get your ideas on paper (i.e. what features you want etc.) and then start coding it. Keep coding until you finish the app.

Your best friends while developing will be http://php.net and StackOverflow.