# Is learning a framework such as Zend or CakePHP while just starting to learn OOP a good or bad idea?

Tags: php, oop, frameworks

I've been studying php for about 6 months now and want to start learning OOP and a framework. When I was learning javascript and jQuery, I learned the best when I was learning and applying both of them at the same time, so now I"m wondering if diving right into learning a framework while learning OOP (up until now I've only done procedural php coding) is a good idea.

Comment: Please see [many other questions along the same lines](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beginner+learn+oop+framework+%5Bphp%5D). I'd say if you can handle the learning curve, go for it. If you can't, keep writing "normal code" until you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [learning php OOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707222/learning-php-oop) - A framework teaches you "framework", not OOP or PHP. Just like jQuery is JavaScript but JavaScript is not jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I'd say Yes it is a good idea. The reason being that many OO concepts get applied in frameworks so you will get lots of practical exposure to various patterns an constructs.

Comment: I've went straight into learning Codeigniter as my framework (since it seemed most newbie friendly) and it's been much easier learning OOP this way. (I've had 6 month php experience before starting to learn Codeigniter two weeks ago)

Answer (score 2):

Learning OOP and learning about MVC is a good idea, before getting into PHP frameworks. Straight away you will have to make design decisions about where you should put different code. If you make the mistakes early, then to improve your design you will have to go back and fix up poor mistakes.

I read a nice answer recently: [How to increase my "advanced" knowledge of PHP further? (quickly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948323/how-to-increase-my-advanced-knowledge-of-php-further-quickly/2948382#2948382)