# PHP fputcsv showing long integers in excel as scientific notation

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I have a simple script that outputs data from my database to a CSV file.

My problem is that when I export mobile numbers, excel sees them as long integers and displays them in scientific notation.

If I go to format cells and change it to a number they all display fine.

Is there a way to set the column as a integer without changing it in excel.

Here is my code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');


$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');


fputcsv($output, array('Book Reference','Company','Type','Site Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Name', 'Email', 'Mobile', 'Team ID'));
```

Below is the code that sits inside my while loop

```
// THIS IS WHERE I SET VARIABLES

fputcsv($output, array($booking_reference,$company,$type,$site_name,$date,$time,$name,$email,$mobile,$team_id));
```

Comment: can't do mucha bout that with CSV, because csv has absolutely no way of indicating formatting of a field. if you want a "large" number to be treated as text, you should probably look into using an excel library to generate a native .xls file, where you CAN force large numbers to be treated as text.

Comment: Import the file into excel and, from there, you can define the field properties. The issue is more with how excel defaults CSV imports.

Comment: I like PHPExcel for generating xls files with formatted cells. This SO thread has many more suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133357/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-xls-file-in-php

Answer (score 2):

I had to deal with this sort of thing once. 
Although it is not very elegant and is not pure CSV. 
The only way I know off to force Excel to cast a value, from a csv-source, is to use a 'formula' as a value in the csv-data.

So ... to force excel to interpret the numbers as text you could use:

....,'="5551212 "',...

Answer (score 1):

CSVs use a delimiter to separate column data. There are no formatting options for specific data types. The issue lies in the fact that Excel defaults the data type automatically. You need to override this when you import your CSV manually.

To do this: For all CSVs, you can import all data as text by going to `Data -> Get External Data from Text`, and then selecting the `Delimited` bullet point, check `My data has headers`, click `Next`, then check the field for `Comma` under the `Delimiters` column, hit `Next` and -- this is the key --  highlight all of the columns in the data preview, and then select `Text` under the `Column data format` before hitting `Finish`.

This will allow for all CSV files to be imported as text, and solves all leading and trailing 0 problems, all scientific notation problems, and ensures that every VLOOKUP matches when making a direct comparison to another text field.

Comment: Yeah I am aware that I can change the settings in Excel, was more looking for a solution for the file itself. May have to look into a library to generate .xls. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid scientific notation, you must add single quotes to each value of the array you want to convert to csv.

This example worked in my case.

```
         function insertquote($value) {
            return "'$value'";
        }



        foreach ($list as $ferow) {
            fputcsv($fp, array_map(insertquote, $ferrow), ';');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had succes by using "Ale DC" answer but changed the "insertquote" function.

```
    foreach ($array as $line) 
            fputcsv($fh, array_map('insertquote', $line), $delimiter);
    
function insertquote($value) {
        return "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$value;
    }
```