# php output sql to excel

Tags: php, sql, phpexcel

How can I use php sql to export to Excel and NOT csv/tsv?

I have googled for it for a while but am only finding multiple results on exporting to csv.

Even if you just point me to the name of the method I can google it from there.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please be more specific? i am unable to understand your requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699301/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php is like the first Google search result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to create XLS file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133357/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-xls-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lib like phpExcel or Spout to create (and read) excel files.

- [phpExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) : lots of options, but slow
- [spout](https://github.com/box/spout) : less options, but much faster than phpExcel