# How to create an Excel from HTML(div based structure) with CSS styling

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am currently working on a request, through which I am trying to export an excel sheet from a div based structure. How can we add styles, so that that the div structure will fit the Excel table structure?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

[From another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133357/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-xls-file-in-php)

> Depends if you want a CSV file or an XLS file. An XLS file can include formatting information for the cells, as well as row/column locking, protections and other features that are impossible in a CSV file. Also, keep in mind that Excel does not correctly support UTF-8 encoded content when opening CSV files.

This means you have to know the format XLS files are made of if you want to style them. Or use the standard CSV extension, without styling.