# Understanding Standard Classes int PHP (and NOT working example)

Tags: php, class

So in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401/hidden-features-of-php/255623#255623) to the question: [Hidden Features of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401/hidden-features-of-php-closed)?

Talks about using standard classes in PHP. Which in his own example looks sweet but I cant get it to work, se [here](http://ideone.com/hHZLS).

The code is:

```
<?php

$person = new stdClass();
$person->name = 'bob';
$person->age = 5;

$string = "$person->name is $person->age years old.";

?>
```

I realize I may be completely misinterpreting the answer but anyway, this is what I understood :)

The this I don't understand is (the most important probably) stdClass(); I read:
[What is stdClass in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php) but I think I'm even more confused now. (I did't find the accepted answer very useful to be honest)

Thanks in advance!!

---

EDIT:

Damn!! I'm sorry guys!! I was not code related!! when I copy the code to ideone.com I just copies some other values with it and prevents it from working (or at least this is my best guess) works just fine in codepad.org, I'm switching!!

Comment: What's your PHP version? It should work properly. What do you not understand about `stdClass`?

Comment: To put it differently: `stdClass` is the `object` basis type, like in other languages. Albeit in PHP it's not really the basis for all objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Works for me.](http://codepad.org/SvXFTRNb)

Is your PHP > 5.1?

Try this

```
var_dump(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, 5.1, '>'));
```

#### Update

[Your example works for me](http://ideone.com/orGt5). Did you forget to output your string? :P

Comment: No no, I was trying in ideone.com directly, maybe I got something else with the copy paste! let me check, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

In order to interpolate object members within strings in older versions of PHP, you should surround them with curly braces:

```
$string = "{$person->name} is {$person->age} years old.";
```

Comment: The braces are not necessary unless you're referring to object properties which are arrays.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob ! problem solved see my edit, sorry, but it does work without the braces like @alex points out!

Answer (score 0):

When you use mysql_fetch_object() it returns an instance of stdClass. The columns are the properties of this class. It's like an anonymous class. It's because PHP doesn't have a class for every possible table in the world. So this is very handy.

Comment: Why are you bringing database access into this?

Comment: Thanks but I did not understand your answer but see my edit anyway! Thanks again!

Comment: It's just an example of where stdClass can be used.