# Restricting eval() to a narrow scope

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a javascript file that reads another file which may contain javascript fragments that need to be eval()-ed. The script fragments are supposed to conform to a strict subset of javascript that limits what they can do and which variables they can change, but I want to know if there is some way to enforce this by preventing the eval from seeing variables in the global scope. Something like the following:

```
function safeEval( fragment )
{
    var localVariable = g_Variable;

    {
        // do magic scoping here so that the eval fragment can see localVariable
        // but not g_Variable or anything else outside function scope

        eval( fragment );
    }
}
```

The actual code doesn't need to look like this--I'm open to any and all weird tricks with closures, etc. But I do want to know if this is even *possible*.

Comment: I don't know whether it will work for `eval` but you can try to switch its execution context (google activation object).

Comment: Take a look at dojox.secure.sandbox implementation.

Comment: Now, what you probably want is a Web Worker.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Short answer**: No. If it's in the global scope, it's available to anything.

**Long answer**: if you're `eval()`ing untrusted code that *really* wants to read or mess with your execution environment, you're screwed. But if you own and trust all code being executed, including that being `eval()`ed, you can fake it by overriding the execution context:

```
function maskedEval(scr)
{
    // set up an object to serve as the context for the code
    // being evaluated. 
    var mask = {};
    // mask global properties 
    for (p in this)
        mask[p] = undefined;

    // execute script in private context
    (new Function( "with(this) { " + scr + "}")).call(mask);
}
```

Again, I must stress:

> This will only serve to shield **trusted** code from the context in which it is executed. If you don't trust the code, DO NOT `eval()` it (or pass it to new `Function()`, or use it in any other way that behaves like `eval()`).

Comment: There is a small gotcha with the `with` approach that has bitten me before. Functions declared within the with block do not have access to the target of the with statement.

Comment: Yeah, i expect a function *declaration* might be "hoisted" out in that case - you'd want to stick to expressions.

Comment: damn .... i cannot say how happy i am :D this is awesome!! now i can complete my template-engine ... have to test more, but i think i already got all... damn... thats pretty cool man ... you know ... to parse expressions loaded from template was hard, but with this its pretty easy :D Do you know any security leaks? i never knew this "with(this)" ... i know that i have to check vor keaywords, to remove evil injection :D

Comment: Read the caveat at the end, @meph - DO NOT feed this anything you didn't write/control.

Comment: can you give examples, how this could end bad? i did check some but didnt found some... i will block variable defining like var test = 1

Comment: Read up on code injections attacks and XSS, @meph - the potential for badness depends entirely on how you control inputs.

Comment: i check if the expression contains = and will block it if the next character is not a = :D I must check for more expressions, but i dont know which else to try.. i would like to get some examples for bad expressions

Comment: The simplest bad expression I can think of would be: 
(function() { this.document.anythingYouWant... }).call(null);

When call is used without a "this" parameter "this" becomes the global context.

Answer (score 8):

Shog9♦'s Answer is great. But if your code is just an expression, the code will be executed and nothing will be returned. For expressions, use

```
function evalInContext(context, js) {

  return eval('with(context) { ' + js + ' }');

}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
var obj = {key: true};

evalInContext(obj, 'key ? "YES" : "NO"');
```

It will return `"YES"`.

If you are not sure if the code to be executed is expressions or statements, you can combine them:

```
function evalInContext(context, js) {

  var value;

  try {
    // for expressions
    value = eval('with(context) { ' + js + ' }');
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
      try {
        // for statements
        value = (new Function('with(this) { ' + js + ' }')).call(context);
      } catch (e) {}
    }
  }

  return value;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is pretty impressive.

Comment: `with()` is not allowed in strict mode

Answer (score 6):

Similar to the dynamic function wrapping script in a `with` block approach above, this allows you to add pseudo-globals to the code you want to execute. You can "hide" specific things by adding them to the context.

```
function evalInContext(source, context) {
    source = '(function(' + Object.keys(context).join(', ') + ') {' + source + '})';

    var compiled = eval(source);

    return compiled.apply(context, values());

    // you likely don't need this - use underscore, jQuery, etc
    function values() {
        var result = [];
        for (var property in context)
            if (context.hasOwnProperty(property))
                result.push(context[property]);
        return result;
    }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/PRh8t/ for an example. Note that `Object.keys` is not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 6):

I accidentally found out I can use Proxy to restrict the scope object, it seems be a lot easier to mask the variable out of the scope. I'm not sure if this method have disadvantages, but so far its work well for me.

```js
function maskedEval(src, ctx = {})
{
    ctx = new Proxy(ctx, {
        has: () => true
    })
    // execute script in private context
    let func = (new Function("with(this) { " + src + "}"));
    func.call(ctx);
}
```

```js
a = 1;
maskedEval("console.log(a)", { console });
maskedEval("console.log(a)", { console, a: 22});

maskedEval("a = 1", { a: 22 })
console.log(a)
```

Comment: This is a very clever approach.

Answer (score 3):

You cant limit the scope of eval

btw see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

There may be some other way to accomplish what it is you want accomplish in the grand scheme of things but you cannot limit the scope of eval in any way.  You may be able to hide certain variables as pseudo private variables in javascript, but I dont think this is what you're going for.

Answer (score 3):

There is a project called Google Caja. You can "sandbox" third party javascript using Caja. https://developers.google.com/caja/

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea. What if you used a static analyzer (something you could build with [esprima](http://esprima.org/), for example) to determine which outside variables the eval'd code uses, and alias them. By "outside code" i mean variables the eval'd code *uses* but does not *declare*. Here's an example:

```
eval(safeEval(
     "var x = window.theX;"
    +"y = Math.random();"
    +"eval('window.z = 500;');"))
```

where safeEval returns the javascript string modified with a context that blocks access to outside variables:

```
";(function(y, Math, window) {"
  +"var x = window.theX;"
  +"y = Math.random();"
  +"eval(safeEval('window.z = 500;');"
"})();"
```

There are a couple things you can do now with this:

- You can ensure that eval'd code can't read the values of outside variables, nor write to them (by passing `undefined` as the function arguments, or not passing arguments). Or you could simply throw an exception in cases where variables are being unsafely accessed.
- You also ensure that variables created by eval don't affect the surrounding scope
- You could allow eval to create variables in the surrounding scope by declaring those variables outside the closure instead of as function parameters
- You could allow read-only access by *copying* values of outside variables and using them as arguments to the function
- You could allow read-write access to specific variables by telling safeEval to not alias those particular names
- You can detect cases where the eval does *not* modify a particular variable and allow it to be automatically excluded from being aliased (eg. Math in this case, is not being modified)
- You could give the eval a context in which to run, by passing in argument values that may be *different* than the surrounding context
- You could capture context changes by also returning the function arguments from the function so you can examine them outside the eval.

Note that the use of `eval` is a special case, since by its nature, it effectively can't be wrapped in another function (which is why we have to do `eval(safeEval(...))`).

Of course, doing all this work may slow down your code, but there are certainly places where the hit won't matter. Hope this helps someone. And if anyone creates a proof of concept, I'd love to see a link to it here ; )

Answer (score 3):

Don't execute code you don't trust. Globals will always be accessible.
If you do trust the code, you can execute it with particular variables in it's scope as follows:

```
(new Function("a", "b", "alert(a + b);"))(1, 2);
```

this is equivalent to:

```
(function (a, b) {
    alert(a + b);
})(1, 2);
```

Comment: Another example: `(new Function("a", "b", "return a + b"))(1, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `eval`. There's an alternative, `js.js`: [JS interpreter written in JS](https://github.com/jterrace/js.js/), so that you can run JS programs in any environment you've managed to setup. Here's an example of its API from the project page:

```
var jsObjs = JSJS.Init();
var rval = JSJS.EvaluateScript(jsObjs.cx, jsObjs.glob, "1 + 1");
var d = JSJS.ValueToNumber(jsObjs.cx, rval);
window.alert(d); // 2
JSJS.End(jsObjs);
```

Nothing scary, as you can see.

Comment: 3MB and only 594KB after gzip compression

Comment: @user645715 1) Try using Closure Compiler to compress it even more. 2) There's 200x slowdown, which is much worse than 3MB source code. 3) There's no other solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Example of a scoped eval for a JavaScript Module that returns an evaluated expression:

```js
function scopedExpr(src, ctx) {
    const scope = Object.assign(Object.keys(globalThis).reduce((acc,k) => { 
        acc[k] = undefined; return acc 
        }, {})
        ,ctx)
    return (new Function("with(this) { return (" + src + ") }")).call(scope)
}
```

### Usage

```js
const result = scopedExpr('{ a: b + c }', { b: 1, c: 2 }) //= { a: 3 }
```

### TypeScript Version

```js
function scopedExpr(src:string, ctx:Record<string,any>) {
    const scope = Object.assign(Object.keys(globalThis).reduce((acc,k) => { 
        acc[k] = undefined; return acc 
        }, {} as Record<string,any>)
        ,ctx)
    return (new Function("with(this) { return (" + src + ") }")).call(scope)
}
```