# NPAPI What is the purpose of the scope parameter to NPN_Evaluate

Tags: npapi

What is the scope argument to `NPN_Evaluate` for, really? In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543533/restricting-eval-to-a-narrow-scope), it's explained that you can not limit the scope of `eval()`. I thought `NPN_Evaluate()` was equivalent to `eval()`?

I am calling `NPN_Evaluate` with different `NPObjects` as the scope, and I don't see any difference. My script is `alert(this.name)` and I was expecting that `this` would be the object I am passing into `NPN_Evaluate` as the scope. But instead, `this` is actually `window`, regardless of what I pass in. Examples on using `NPN_Evaluate` on the net show people always using the window object...

I'm a little unsure of what's going on, so I am not ruling out a mistake in my code just yet, however from what I can see, the above seems to be the case. Any information on the intended use of the scope argument would be welcome.

Comment: Further testing reveals that this behaviour only appears in one of my target browsers (webkit based). I'd still appreciate information, though, especially if it's confirming that I'm looking at a bug.