# Why are closures not formed while doing dynamic code evaluation using the Function constructor?

Tags: javascript, closures

So of the two ways of dynamic code evaluation (`Function constructor` vs `eval()`), the former one do not create closure but the later one does? Why is a closure not formed while using `Function` constructors to evaluate some code? Is this behavior mandated by the ECMA specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this behavior mandated by the ECMA specification?

It is. [Section 15.3.2.1](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.2.1) describes the algorithm that is executed when `new Function` is evaluated. Note the last step:

> 11. Return a new Function object created as specified in [13.2](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2) passing *P* as the *FormalParameterList* and body as the [*FunctionBody*](http://es5.github.io/#x13). Pass in the [Global Environment](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3) as the *Scope* parameter and *strict* as the *Strict* flag.

The scope in which the function will be run is the global scope, not the current scope where the call is made, hence it cannot form a closure.

On the other hand, code executed through `eval` is run the current scope ([§10.4.2](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.2)):

> b. Set the LexicalEnvironment to the same value as the [LexicalEnvironment](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2) of the calling execution context.
>   c. Set the VariableEnvironment to the same value as the VariableEnvironment of the calling execution context.

Comment: But why is it designed this way? What would be the side effect if function objects were created with the local scope?

Comment: If you want them in the local scope, why not write them as literals?

Comment: @PaulS. the function body and the parameters may come from outside. So may not be possible to write as a literal.

Comment: @Geek: I cannot answer you that. Probably only someone who worked on the specification can.

Comment: @FelixKling I understand. My question was is this mandated by the specification and the answer is *yes*. You also quoted the source. So I am accepting your answer.

Comment: @Geek: It's safer for example. If you need to eval code, then you can choose not to let if affect your local scope by using the `Function` constructor instead of `eval`. See the discussions on where, when and how [not] to to use eval.

Comment: @Bergi probably you wanted to put a link in your comment.

Comment: @Geek: Nah, I wanted you to do a web search :-) The [top SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bjavascript%5d%20use%20eval) would be http://stackoverflow.com/q/543533, http://stackoverflow.com/q/197769 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/86513

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to see closures being effected by *Function* and `eval`.

```
var z = 0;
(function () {                                 // Local    | Global
    var x = 0, y = 0;                          // x  y  z  | x      y      z
    console.log(x, y, z);                      // 0  0  0  |
    console.log(window.x, window.y, window.z); //          | undef  undef  0
    new Function('var x = 1; y = 1; z = 1')(); // Function set 1
    console.log(x, y, z);                      // 0  0  1  |
    console.log(window.x, window.y, window.z); //          | undef  1      1
    eval('var x = 2; y = 2; z = 2');           // Eval set 2
    console.log(x, y, z);                      // 2  2  2  |
    console.log(window.x, window.y, window.z); //          | undef  1      2
}());
```

You can see that `eval` is working in the current scope whereas *Function* is invoked as a function in the global scope.

But really, please try to avoid using either.

Comment: Dynamic evaluation is very useful and can be used to gain significant performance boosts. Using `Function` doesn't cause your code to be dynamically scoped either like `with` and `eval` do,.