# Javascript with() performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I remember reading quite a while ago that `with()` has some serious performance impacts in JavaScript due to its possibly non-deterministic change to the scope stack.  I am having difficulty finding any recent discussion of this.  Is this still true?

Answer (score 4):

It's not so much that with has performance impacts as it is just [inadvisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement/61676#61676). See [also](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

For the record, it's deterministic from the browsers perspective, but not the developer who needs to place a lot more trust than usual in the context of the variable.

Comment: I just meant it could be non-deterministic, such as `with(getSomeObjectBasedOnUserInput())`.  I remember something about because of this statement the JIT/optimizer can't do anything ahead of time, and can't reuse optimization data because the user input might change.