# javascript 'with' reserved word

Tags: javascript

What does the Javascript 'with' keyword do? I tried searching online but no luck. 
Thanks.

Comment: Funny, I searched for "javascript with keyword" on google and got a great explanation from the very first result

Comment: Part 2: in what version of javascript does it first appear?

Comment: Yep. with-keyword, or with-statement and you're on track.

Comment: Please don't use `with`.

Comment: @Eric: Funny, I tried that and it's a page talking about the `this` keyword, no mention of `with`.  But the sentiment is valid.

Comment: I am with kangax Do NOT use "with" please.

Comment: @Joe: I think @Eric searched with quotes.

Answer (score 8):

You can save some typing with it:

```
with(Math) {
  var x= cos(PI);
  var y= sin(PI);
}
```

Here's an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement) on its legitimacy.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to VB's With statement, where it creates a block and allows you to use whatever you put in the with statement inside the block.

Here's a [reference](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsstmwith.htm).

And an example:

```
function generateNumber()
{
    with(Math)
    {
        var x, y ,z 
        x= cos(3 * PI) + sin (LN10) 
        y= tan(14 * E)
        z=(pow(x,2) + pow(y,2)) * random()* 100;
    }
    return z;
}
document.write(generateNumber());
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates a block of code that allows you to use whatever's inside the with statement inside that block.

Examples here:
http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5700

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to perform operations in the context of a certain object, but it has some downsides. It can sometimes make your references ambiguous. It usually isn't a problem, but if you just type a few extra characters you can be 100% sure that you're the browser's doing what you think its doing. :D

Comment: "In the context of a certain object" sounds ambiguous. Context, for example, is often understood as `this` value of a function. Another interpretation is execution context of a function. `with`, of course, does not affect either — it merely injects an object in question in front of current scope chain.

Answer (score 0):

There are some neat tricks you can do with it, but other then that using with is discouraged.

See [this SO answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement). Make sure you read Shog9's answer.