# Any examples of a non-trivial and useful example of the 'with' keyword?

Tags: javascript, with-statement

I still find the `with` keyword a bit...*enigmatic*.

Briefly, `with` behaves like this:

```
with (obj) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This adds `obj` to the head of the scope chain and then executes the with-block. When the block is finished it removes `obj` from the head of the scope chain.

According to [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/with), this allows you to do stuff like

```
var a, x;
var r = 10;
with(Math) {
    a = PI * r * r;
    x = r * cos(PI / 2);
}
```

So I can reference properties of `Math` -- like `PI` -- directly, without saying `Math.PI`. Which is fine, but kind of useless.

Can anyone provide an example of an interesting usage of `with`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there legitimate uses for JavaScript's "with" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to the standard closure solution using functions inside of a for loop:

```
<a  href="#">blah</a><br>
<a  href="#">blah</a><br>
<a  href="#">foo</a><br>
<script>
    (function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for ( var i = anchors.length; i--; ) {
            var link = anchors[i];
            with ({ number: i }) {
                link.onclick = function() {
                    alert(number);
                };
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Credit to `nlogax` for providing a solution which I pretty much ripped off:
[Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Here's the standard solution:

```
<script>
    (function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for ( var i = anchors.length; i--; ) {
        var link = anchors[i];
        (function(i) {
            link.onclick = function() {
                alert(i)
            }
        })(i);
    }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please please provide the standard closure solution version for comparison?

Answer (score 4):

It should be said here that the `with` statement in JavaScript is widely deprecated.

See Douglas Crockford's [With Statement Considered Harmful](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

I can't say it any better than he did (seriously, follow the link), but in short if you do this:

```
with (mySuperLongObjectReferenceThatIHateTyping) {
  propertyAlpha = 'a';
  propertyBeta = 2;
  propertyGamma = false;
}
```

You can't know by looking at that code if you're assigning values to properties of the mySuperLongObjectReferenceThatIHateTyping object or of the global object (window).

Crockford recommends this:

```
var o = mySuperLongObjectReferenceThatIHateTyping;
o.propertyAlpha = 'a';
o.propertyBeta = 2;
o.propertyGamma = false;
```

Which is unambiguous. Or you could even use a function so you have scope and don't create another global variable:

```
(function(o) {
  o.propertyAlpha = 'a';
  o.propertyBeta = 2;
  o.propertyGamma = false;
})(mySuperLongObjectReferenceThatIHateTyping);
```

Comment: The money quote: "If you can’t read a program and be confident that you know what it is going to do, you can’t have confidence that it is going to work correctly. For this reason, the `with` statement should be avoided."

Answer (score 3):

[John Resig's javascript microtemplating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) shows some interesting use for with.

Answer (score 2):

I regularly use it to add multiple CSS properties to a `style` object, eg

```
with(document.body.style) {
    color = 'green';
    background = 'red';
}
```

Also, I used it [at least once](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/geo/distance.js) to assign the properties of an object to local variables without having to store a reference to the object itself.

It's also an alternative to closures when you want to take a 'snapshot' of the value of a variable:

```
var foo = [];
for(var i = 10; i--;)
    with({ i : i }) foo[i] = function() { document.writeln(i); };

// prints 0..9
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; ++i)
    foo[i]();
```

Keep in mind that `with` can seriously impact performance as the prototype chain of the object you added to the lexical environment has to be checked first when resolving any variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The with statement in JS is like the with statement in say VB.net.
It is simply a way to avoid repetition with properties / methods of an object.

For instance, assume a label control is being modified based on an event / action.  That
label control has properties such as FontColor, CSSClass, Visibility etc.

Instead of the programmer writing:

```
myLabel.FontColor=Color.Blue
myLabel.CSSClass="SomeCSSClass"
myLabel.Visiblity=True
myLabel.Text = "Hello World"
```

We can shorten that to:

```
With myLabel
  .Text = "Hello World"
  .FontColor = Color.Blue
  .CssClass="SomeCSSClass"
  .Visibility=True
End With
```

Comment: But the JavaScript statement has some serious disadvantages, unlike the VB statement.

Answer (score 1):

I originally answered this on Apr 14, 2012.

Update Aug. 2022: I no longer try to use `with`. And the crap I wrote here about some complex style of doing class-like objects, I now judge inappropriate.