# Why this js code works?

Tags: javascript

```
if (!wysiwyg_toolbarButtons) {
    var wysiwyg_toolbarButtons = new Array(
        //command, display name, value, title, prompt/function, default text
        ["bold", "Strong", WYSIWYG_VALUE_NONE, "Give text strength"],
        ["italic", "Emphasis", WYSIWYG_VALUE_NONE, "Give text emphasis"],
        ["createlink", "Link", WYSIWYG_VALUE_PROMPT, "Create a hyperlink", "Enter the URL:", "http://"],
        ["unlink", "Unlink", WYSIWYG_VALUE_NONE, "Remove hyperlink"],
        ["insertimage", "Image", WYSIWYG_VALUE_PROMPT, "Insert an image", "Enter the URL of the image:", "http://"],
        ["inserthorizontalrule", "Rule", WYSIWYG_VALUE_NONE, "Insert horizontal rule"],
        ["div"], // place a toolbar divider
        ["formatblock", "Headling 1", "<H1>", "Make top level heading"],
        ["formatblock", "Headling 2", "<H2>", "Make 2nd level heading"],
        ["formatblock", "Headling 3", "<H3>", "Make 3rd level heading"],
        ["formatblock", "Paragraph", "<P>", "Make a paragraph"],
        ["formatblock", "Monospace", "<PRE>", "Make paragraph monospaced text"],
        ["insertunorderedlist", "List", null, "Make an unordered list"],
        ["insertorderedlist", "Ordered List", null, "Make an ordered list"],
        ["div"], // place a toolbar divider
        ["toggleview", "Source", "Compose", "Switch views"]
    );
}
```

It's from [this file](http://www.peej.co.uk/sandbox/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.js)，with a demo [here](http://www.peej.co.uk/sandbox/wysiwyg/)

My problem is:why doesn't it report "ReferenceError: wysiwyg_toolbarButtons is not defined"?

Comment: just tried: `if (!wysiwyg_toolbarButtons) {}` in Rhino and it blows with an exception...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript in the web browser searches attributes in the **window object**. Accessing an unknown attribute does not throw an error, so in fact it is evaluated as something like this:

```
if( !window.wysiwyg_toolbarButtons ) { }
```

Try `if( !wtf ) { alert('error'); }` and `if( !window.wtf ) { alert('no error'); }` in the Firebug Console.

**EDIT**

Currently the console in firebug evals the code using `with( window ) { ..console..code.. }`. But the "with" statement is tricky, example:

```
>>> alert(location);
= eval( "with( window ) { alert(location); }" );
OK, "location" attribute found in window

>>> alert(wtf);
= eval( "with( window ) { alert(wtf); }" );
ERROR, "wtf" not found in window, and not in global scope, throws ReferenceError
```

The implicit window object in the browser behaves differently than as it would be used with the "with" statement.

Comment: ah! makes sense then with regards to the behavior I see when testing with Rhino. +1

Comment: But when I type `location`,firebug gives the result of window.location correctly

Comment: Yes, seems to be a bug - or lets say subtlety - in firebug. I guess firebug searches the "window scope" manually for an attribute that matches, and falls back to throw the exception if no match was found.

Comment: The "bug" is because Firebug executes the input wrapped in a _with_ statement: `with( window } { ..console..code.. }`. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement

Comment: firebug issue tracker (somewhere there.. lost the url), and source code: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.5/content/firebug/commandLine.js#242

Answer (score 2):

The first thing the code does is a truthiness evaluation of `wysiwyg_toolbarButtons`, since it evaluates to `false` being `undefined` then the block enters and the variable is defined.

Comment: But when I type `if(!nosuchvariable)alert(1);` in firebug,it just reports a error

Comment: Truthiness is a bit of a funny word, but he means something like "truth-value test", i.e., does `wysiwyg_toolbarButtons` evaluate to true or false? `undefined` is also considered `false`.

Comment: Truthy is fairly common terminology for javascript (at least in my world)... "such values can be called "truthy" and "falsy," respectively." - From "A re-introduction to JavaScript" by Simon Willison.

Comment: @unknown (google) - Are you just trying to execute code directly inline with firebug?

Comment: I believe the reason this is happening is because the script cannot evaluate that the variable in question will ever be defined. Try `if(!nosuchvariable){var nosuchvariable=1; alert(nosuchvariable);}`.. does that work at all?

Answer (score 1):

What that code is doing is checking if `wysiwyg_toolbarButtons` is defined, and if it is not, it's defining and initializing it.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is not block scoped so the var declaration inside the if is just the same as if it had happened before the if.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Yep, I misunderstood what I was saying. Sorry for the bad answer.

<s>Based on your code, `wysiwyg_toolbarButtons` is created local to the `if` statement. The `var` declaration tells JavaScript that this is a new variable, and anything inside of the `if` statement's scope will use this new variable.</s>

I'm assuming this code is functioning with the statements like that. Whether or not it successfully changes `wysiwyg_toolbarButtons` (or `wysiwyg_elementMap`, as I scan the JS file) outside of that scope doesn't matter. Keeping the declaration like that is bad coding practice, because it won't work like that in other languages.

Otherwise, I'm not going to restate what Quintin, Andreas, and Dimitar already said.

Comment: It doesn't seem that an `if` statement creates a "scope". I tried a simple test in Rhino and a variable (e.g. `var hi=rue`) declared inside an `if` is visible outside.

Comment: Right, but I made my point more because it's a smart programming practice and something that could _potentially_ be dangerous to other languages.

If I understand correctly, the only reason it works like that is because browsers conformed to the poor practices of the scripters instead of forcing them to learn good practices. Also, because of how JavaScript actually houses its variables, it would make sense that the scope doesn't work exactly how it should.

It's unimportant if you'll never code in any other language or never reuse a variable name, I suppose.

Comment: @Jeff: javascript scope is tricky, but a lot of code depends on how it works (e.g. javascript "namespaces"). It has nothing to do with browsers implementations. Its supposed to be like it is, its standard. This example is NO bad practice, its fine.

Comment: @Jeff: "If I understand correctly, the only reason it works like that is because browsers conformed to the poor practices of the scripters instead of forcing them to learn good practices." No, it works like that by design. Blocks in JavaScript don't introduce new scopes, only functions do. This is a feature, not a bug. Also, I don't really see how coding like that is bad practice just because "it won't work like that in other languages." By that logic, prototypical inheritance should be avoided since it doesn't work in (most) other languages either.

Comment: Well, this was an ignorant answer for me to have made. Thanks jldupont for catching my error, and frunsi and bcat for better explaining why I was wrong.