# Why use "with" keyword in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Are there legitimate uses for JavaScript’s “with” statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement)

I recently discovered that in JavaScript, one can do something like the following:

```
with (document) {
    write('foo');
    body.scrollTop = x;
}
```

The down side of this is that each variable needs to be checked to see if it belongs to the document object, creating a significant overhead.

Alternatively, one could do something like this:

```
var d = document;
d.write('foo');
d.body.scrollTop = x;
```

Are there any situations where the use of the 'with' keyword is justified?

Comment: Here are some blog posts in support of the with keyword. But please read the YUI blog entry that azazul posted as well! [http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/12/with-worlds-most-misunderstood.html](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/12/with-worlds-most-misunderstood.html)
[http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/12/with-some-good-example.html](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/12/with-some-good-example.html)

Comment: @Abel, you're right, this answers my question nicely as well as sticking a giant caveat on there too.

Comment: @Annie: I think you should paste some quotes here instead of simply linking two related articles. What if they lead to a 404 (or similar) HTTP code later (e.g. because these articles were moved/deleted)?

Comment: **Using `with` is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose properties you want to access to a temporary variable.** Source:[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

Answer (score 94):

Just don't use it:
http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

> JavaScript's `with` statement was intended to provide a shorthand for writing recurring accesses to objects. So instead of writing
>
> ```
> ooo.eee.oo.ah_ah.ting.tang.walla.walla.bing = true;
> ooo.eee.oo.ah_ah.ting.tang.walla.walla.bang = true;
> ```
>
> You can write
>
> ```
> with (ooo.eee.oo.ah_ah.ting.tang.walla.walla) {
>     bing = true;
>     bang = true;
> }
> ```
>
> That looks a lot nicer. Except for one thing. There is no way that you can tell by looking at the code which `bing` and `bang` will get modifed. Will `ooo.eee.oo.ah_ah.ting.tang.walla.walla` be modified? Or will the global variables `bing` and `bang` get clobbered? It is impossible to know for sure...
>
> If you can't read a program and be confident that you know what it is going to do, you can't have confidence that it is going to work correctly. For this reason, the `with` statement should be avoided...

Comment: I can't express this enough: any "with"-like syntax, like the one for JavaScript and Delphi, where you're not explicitly specifying which identifiers belong to the "scoped" object, and which one aren't, are **evil**, don't use that syntax in those languages. In particular, future changes might change the behavior of that code without warning. If that isn't a bug just waiting to happen, then I don't know what is.

Comment: For instance, Visual Basic.NET got it right, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb(VS.80).aspx, where they force you to prefix all identifiers belonging to the scoped object with a dot.

Comment: Yeah, VB (.NET and before) got it right, but they also got it wrong: if you use late-binding, your still in the same problem. And performance with `with` is slower then without (for whatever odd reason).

Comment: @John: the only justification I can find is where code becomes clearer when using it. If you find yourself in such a situation, you can use it...

Comment: @John (2): about justification, check Annie's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931186/with-keyword-in-javascript/1931202#1931202

Comment: Pathetically, this is not just a knee-jerk reaction, but a *parroted* knee-jerk reaction.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19012662/34806 for using with, with requirejs

Answer (score 23):

Despite advice to the contrary almost everywhere, I think that there are uses for "with". For example, I'm working on a domain model framework for Javascript, which uses the underscore character in much the same way that jQuery uses "$". This means that without "with", I have lots of underscores scattered through my code in ways that make it less readable. Here's a random line from an application using the framework:

```
_.People().sort(_.score(_.isa(_.Parent)),'Surname','Forename');
```

whereas with "with" it would look like

```
with (_) {
    ...

    People().sort(score(isa(Parent)),'Surname','Forename');

    ...
}
```

What would be really useful is a read-only version of "with".

Comment: Not always SLOWER runtime give you side effects. Its negligible if you don't run it thousand times.

Comment: These days, with ES6 object destructuring, you could instead do `const { People, score, isa, Parent } = _;`, and not bring on all the nasty risks of `with (_)`.

Comment: @CamJackson Yes, but people must take note that destructuring clones the value of the property.  Therefore, if the value of the property is a primitive, then it will not actually be writing to the original object.  This will not affect properties that have values of objects because they are just references to that data:

```
const person = {
  name: "Harry Potter",
};

let { name } = person;

name = "Draco Malfoy"; // assigning to the termporary primitive
console.log(person.name); // Harry Potter
```

Therefore, it's best practice to prefer using `const { ... } = foo`.

Answer (score 6):

I would avoid using it in production code because it's ambiguous but there is an alternative solution to the for-loop-closure solution by using `with` to mimic the `let` binding, here's a copy of my previous answer:

An alternative to the standard closure solution using functions inside of a for loop:

```
<a  href="#">blah</a><br>
<a  href="#">blah</a><br>
<a  href="#">foo</a><br>
<script>
    (function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for ( var i = anchors.length; i--; ) {
            var link = anchors[i];
            with ({ number: i }) {
                link.onclick = function() {
                    alert(number);
                };
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Credit to `nlogax` for providing a solution which I pretty much ripped off:
[Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Here's the standard solution:

```
<script>
    (function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for ( var i = anchors.length; i--; ) {
        var link = anchors[i];
        (function(i) {
            link.onclick = function() {
                alert(i)
            }
        })(i);
    }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Please make sure you state what part is "ambiguous", as the JavaScript interpreter and/or compiler is never confused about what to use for the identifier. It's future changes and/or what a programmer might interpret an identifier as that is the problem.

Comment: **With modern `const` scoping rules these days you do not need neither of the two**.  Just say `for (var i=anchors.length; i--;) { const ii = i; .. alert(ii) ..`.  Or even better: `for (let i=..) .. alert(i) ..` because `let` introduces it's own looped scope.  Note that in modern Browsers simple examples like yours can be shortened even further: `document.getElementsByTagName('a').forEach((link,i) => link.onclick = () => alert(i))`  But this is an entirely different story.

Comment: @Tino `let` creates a new scope; this is nice. But `let` does not limit the scope; this is not so nice. Lisp did it right, but JavaScript forgot that this could be done right. The nice thing about `with` is, it limits the scope.

Comment: @ceving Instead of `with ({number:i}) { ..`  you can as well write `{ let number=i; ..`.  AFAICS this gives the same limited scope (but `let` probably does a better runtime optimization).  Please correct me if I did not understand your argument correctly.  I will recognize it, but do not want to continue to discuss this in comments ;)  PS: Of course: `with ({i}) { ..` cannot be expressed the same with `let`, as `{ let i=i; ..` makes no sense.