# Javascript dynamically created functions in an object

Tags: javascript

I'm just studying javascript and I faced an issue related to scoping.

Here's the code

```js
function User (properties) {
    for (var i in properties) {
        (function ()  {
            this ['get' + i] = function () {
                return properties [i];
            };
        }) ();
    }
}

var me = new User ({
    Id : 54,
    Name : 'ohyou'
});

console.log (me.getName ());
console.log (me.getId ());
```

How I want it to work: it should create two functions `getName` and `getId` that belong to the `me` object.

How it works: it creates two functions just as I want, but they belong to the `window`

What I tried:

- I tried removing the function on the line 3. It does what I want, but now it returns the `name` "ohyou" two times, instead of returning the `id` and the `name`
- I tried using the functions from the `window` scope, the problem as in the previous case persists - it returns the `name` twice.

The question: what am I doing wrong and how do I make it work as I want?

P.S. Making this post using phone, sorry for possible typos or formatting issues. Also, please forgive me my english skills.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of a duplicate somewhere. Best solution IMO is to drop the loop, and use `Object.keys(properties).forEach`,

Comment: You can deal with `this` or you can deal with `that`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript

Comment: Changed the loop to the function you suggested, but, apparently, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to understand why the following code works:

```js
function User(properties) {
    for (var i in properties) {
        with ({ i: i, self: this, props: properties }) {
            self["get" + i] = function () {
                return props[i];
            };
        }
    }
}

var me = new User({
    Id: 54,
    Name: "ohyou"
});

alert(me.getName());
alert(me.getId());
```

This is an example of one of the legitimate uses of the `with` statement.

I find the `with` statement to be more succinct than using an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) as others are suggesting.

**Edit:** The `with` keyword is not bad if you use it correctly. There are some legitimate uses of with:

http://webreflection.blogspot.in/2009/12/with-worlds-most-misunderstood.html

---

The reason your code doesn't work is because every function has it's own value of `this`. Hence when you immediately invoke the function expression within the `for` loop, the value of `this` inside the function is no longer your new object. It is `window`. To solve that problem you could do something like:

```
(function (i, self, props) {
    self["get" + i] = function () {
        return props[i];
    };
}(i, this, properties))
```

However using the `with` statement is clean and faster. It's faster because you're not calling a function.

Comment: Hey Aadit - I personally like the usage of 'with' here, but the docs I've read shun away from it - though I believe your usage here is nice.

Comment: @jamesemanon The `with` statement is not bad. See the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1931186/783743

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly even with just `{i: i}`, but I don't understand why. And I also don't understand why it didn't work in my case.

Comment: @ohyou I added an explanation as to why your code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
function User (properties) {
    var that = this;
    for (var i in properties) {
        (function (i)  {

            that ['get' + i] = function () {
                return properties [i];
            };

        }) (i);
    }
}

var me = new User ({
    Id : 54,
    Name : 'ohyou'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid all these closures and other things if you use `Object.keys` and then `forEach`, which already introduces a new scope. Then you'd have to pass the `this` value, which is the second parameter:

```
function User(properties) {
  Object.keys(properties).forEach(function(k) {
    this['get'+ k] = function() {
      return properties[k]
    }
  },this)
}
```

Comment: Although this is terribly slow. First loop through all the properties to get the key names. Then loop through them again, running the callback function each time.

Comment: Nothing to worry about, engines are plenty fast. I'd stay away from `for` loops if I want readable code, and better abstractions.

Comment: I guess everybody has their own style. I like writing functional code too, but not in JavaScript. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you must remember, **any function that does not belong to any object, will always belong to window object**.

For example if we modify your object and add a new method,

```
me.doSomeWork = function(){
   this.myLuckyNumber = 10;
   var that = this;
   function doubleMyLuckyNumber(){
      console.log(this); //window
      that.myLuckyNumber = that.myLuckyNumber * 2;     
   } 

  doubleMyLuckyNumber();  
};

me.doSomeWork();
console.log(me.myLuckyNumber) //outputs 20
```

So always save the reference to a **var** to use it in inner methods. You can use any of the way that others suggested but I prefer James emanon's approach.

Comment: I knew that, thanks for reminding. I just got confused with the inner scope I didn't pass my data to.