# Behavior of local variables in JavaScripts with()-statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed some weird (and to my knowledge undefined behavior, by the ECMA 3.0 Spec at least), take the following snippet:

```
var foo = { bar: "1", baz: "2" };
alert(bar);
with(foo) {
    alert(bar);
    alert(bar);
}
alert(bar);
```

It crashes in both Firefox and Chrome, because "bar" doesn't exist in the first alert(); statement, this is as expected. But if you add a declaration of bar inside the with()-statement, so it looks like this:

```
var foo = { bar: "1", baz: "2" };
alert(bar);
with(foo) {
    alert(bar);
    var bar = "g2";
    alert(bar);
}
alert(bar);
```

It will produce the following:

`undefined, 1, g2, undefined`

It seems as if you create a variable inside a with()-statement most browsers (tested on Chrome or Firefox) will make that variable exist outside that scope also, it's just set to undefined. Now from my perspective bar should only exist inside the with()-statement, and if you make the example even weirder:

```
var foo = { bar: "1", baz: "2" };
var zoo;
alert(bar);
with(foo) {
    alert(bar);
    var bar = "g2";
    zoo = function() {
        return bar;
    }
    alert(bar);
}
alert(bar);
alert(zoo());
```

It will produce this:

`undefined, 1, g2, undefined, g2`

So the `bar` inside the with()-statement does not exist outside of it, yet the runtime somehow "automagically" creates a variable named bar that is undefined in its top level scope (global or function) but this variable does not refer to the same one as inside the with()-statement, and that variable will only exist if a with()-statement has a variable named bar that is *defined* inside it.

Very weird, and inconsistent. Anyone have an explanation for this behavior? There is nothing in the ECMA Spec about this.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from ECMA-262, 3rd edition, §12.2, as

> Variables are created when the execution scope is entered. A *Block* does not define a new execution scope.

and

> A variable with an *Initialiser* is assigned the value of its *AssignmentExpression* when the *VariableStatement*  is executed, not when the variable is created.

This means you have to think of a declaration with initializer as two seperate steps: first, you create a new variable in the function-local (global) scope when entering the function (executing the script), but you don't assign a value until reaching the statement. In your examples, at this point the scope chain has changed due to `with()`, and the assignment sees the overloaded varriable, leaving the newly created one `undefined`.

This means

```
with({ foo : 42 }) {
    var foo = 'bar';
}
```

is parsed as

```
with({ foo : 42 }) {
    var foo;
    foo = 'bar';
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
var foo;
({ foo : 42 }).foo = 'bar';
```

and therefore leaving `foo` uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just misunderstanding the scoping a bit.  Not that I blame you, if you're coming from **most** other languages it makes you go "WTF?".  Javascript has what I call "FUBAR Scoping" (I'm sure there's a proper term here but I never bothered to learn it...knowing how it works > knowing what it's called, at least to me).

[Let's make the example even simpler](http://jsfiddle.net/T8DVK/):

```
with({}) {
    var foo = "test";​
}
alert(foo); //alerts "test"
```

`with()` allows block level definition of a variable, for being passed into a scope ([good answer demonstrating this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement/185283#185283)).  But...it doesn't restrict the variable to this scope, it is available afterwards, [here's a better example](http://jsfiddle.net/XsGkd/):

```
with({ bar: 1}) {
    this.foo = "test";
    alert(bar); //alerts: 1"1"
    alert(this); //alerts: "DOMwindow"
}
alert(foo);
```

If `with()` was a closure to the element you're dealing with, then `this` would refer to the `{ bar: 1}` object we passed into the with, but it doesn't :).  `this` in this case is still the global context of `window`.  Since you're still executing in this context, any variables you define there will be available in that context, and therefore available later in the function, after the `with()`, because they're defined much **higher** in scope than you would think.  Intuition tells you it's defined in a more constrained scope: within the `with()`...but javascript is different, it all depends what context your closure is running in.

I tried to find a good description for this behavior that gives a lot more scoping examples, [this is the best I could find for you](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html).  Overall this is more of a closure/scoping question than `with()` explicitly, this site covers the overall concept in more detail in case I did a terrible job of explaining it...I know it's a backwards concept in many respects, sorry!

​