# In Javascript, when is a new scope created? (with a new function and in a "with" statement) Are these the only 2 situations?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

In Javascript, when is a new scope created?  The 2 situations I know of are:

1. with a new function  (**update** on 2012/09, I think it needs to be a function invocation, not just a function definition)
2. in a "with" statement

as a note, any new block (in if-then-else, loops, or just beginning a block for no other reason) won't create a new scope.

Is there a third situation where a new scope is created besides the two situations above?  Thanks.

Comment: EcmaScript 5 strict mode no longer supports the with statement.

Comment: Jian Lin, it's customary to accept answer's to your questions. Not so much for the answerer's rep, but so that the rest of the interested community knows that a conclusion was reached.

Comment: re definition vs. invokation: I believe scope is a property of the function. When the function is called, a context is created to hold the values for the variables in the function's scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a third case where the scope chain is augmented (besides the `let` mozilla-extension that [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730858/in-javascript-when-is-a-new-scope-created-with-a-new-function-and-in-a-with/2730961#2730961) mentions), when a `catch` block is evaluated:

> The production Catch : catch
>   (Identifier ) Block is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Let C be the parameter that has been passed to this production.
> 2. Create a new object as if by the expression new Object().
> 3. Create a property in the object Result(2). The property's name is
>      Identifier, valueisC. value, and
>      attributes are { DontDelete }.
> 4. Add Result(2) to the front of the **scope chain**.
> 5. Evaluate Block.
> 6. Remove Result(2) from the front of the **scope chain**.
> 7. Return Result(5).

So basically, a new object is created, with a property named like the Identifier passed to `catch`, this new object is added to the scope  chain, so we are able to use that identifier within the `catch` block.

```
try {
  throw "error";
} catch (identifier) {
  // `identifier` accessible here..
}
```

But keep in mind that it only *augments* the current scope temporarily, to introduce the `catch` Identifier, any variable declared inside will be simply *hoisted* to the top of it enclosing function.

Comment: Excellent, had never given catch evaluation a second thought before reading this!

Comment: In older versions of Firefox, you could actually get ahold of the newly created scope object!

`function getScope() { try { throw function () { return this; }; } catch (f) { return f(); } }`

Usually when a function using `this` was called without being a method, it would return the global object.  But the implementers read "as though by the expression new Object()" literally and implemented it as an object inheriting from the previous scope. Once you got a scope object, you could walk up the prototype chain to get to the others.

Answer (score 6):

There's also the [let statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Block_scope_with_let_%28Merge_into_let_Statement%29). Keep in mind that `let (...) {}`, like `with (...){}`, does not create a new scope for variables introduced *within* the block. However, [let **definitions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#let_definitions) *can* create variables scoped to the block (any block) they're defined in.

**Fair warning:** as has been pointed out in comments, while `let` is part of JavaScript 1.7 (the Mozilla dialect of ECMA-262/ECMAScript), it is *not* part of ECMAScript, and will likely not work any time soon in browsers other than Firefox. Also note that while [`with` can be used as a stand-in for let statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement/185283#185283) in current implementations of ECMAScript, the "strict" mode proposed for the pending ECMA-262 5th edition disallows this as well. If you're concerned about writing cross-plaform, future-proof code (*and you should be...*) then **stick with functions for scope control**!

Comment: So tempted to +1 because you're right, but this might cause a bit of confusion since it's not widely implemented yet.  Oh... what the heck, you earned it!

Comment: @Andy, is not widely implemented because it is a *Mozilla Extension* available only on SpiderMonkey and Rhino engines, and is not part of the ECMAScript Standard.

Comment: @CMS, yes.  I (admittedly, mistakenly) wrote *yet* because `let` was part of the intended ECMAScript 4 spec that never came to be and my brain tends to lean toward the fact that it may return in a future update to the standard.

Comment: @Andy, Yes, I also think that `let` will be part of *ECMAScript Harmony*, the next step...

Answer (score -3):

this will also refer to the object you are in:

```
a = {
   f: function(){ ... },
   b: function(){this.f()}
}
a.b() //calls a.f
```

Comment: That's not a new scope; if it were, you could just do f() in b without using this.