# With (or similar) statement in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

Very simple question: I want to optimize the following jQuery code with maximum readability, optimal performance and minimum fuss (fuss = declaring new variables etc):

```
$(".addthis_toolbox").append('<a class="addthis_button_delicious"></a>');
$(".addthis_toolbox").append('<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>');
$(".addthis_toolbox").append('<a class="addthis_button_google"></a>');
$(".addthis_toolbox").append('<a class="addthis_button_reddit"></a>');
.
.
.
$(".addthis_toolbox").append('<a class="addthis_button_yetanotherservice"></a>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does have the `with` statement:

```
with($(".addthis_toolbox"))
{
    append('<a class="addthis_button_delicious"></a>');
    ...
}
```

You might run into some confusing issues regarding variable scope `using` the with statement though.

You could use chaining to achieve the same thing:

```
$(".addthis_toolbox").append('<a class="addthis_button_delicious"></a>')
                     .append(...)
                     .append(...);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the Javascript community is virtually unanimous in condemning the `with` statement as an extremely bad idea. It is **not** an "optimization" since it generally results in poor performance. It can also cause memory leaks.  Really, it's not a good idea.

Comment: @Pointy - *Most* things taken *from* VB were misguided :), oh yeah I said it.

Comment: @Nick Craver - I'm with you on that one.

Comment: @Justin - Not my vote either (see my profile, I *very* rarely do that)...it is a valid solution, but I do agree with @Pointy's statement here, `with` is generally a bad idea, for readability *and* performance.

Comment: @Nick Pascal had "with"; I'm pretty sure the idea predates VB by a couple decades!

Comment: @Pointy - Yeah...but it's tainted now, guilty by association :) I feel dirty when I write "End If" in oracle even ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can just keep chaining on the same jQuery object, like this:

```
$(".addthis_toolbox").append('<a class="addthis_button_delicious"></a>')
                     .append('<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>')
                     .append('<a class="addthis_button_google"></a>')
                     .append('<a class="addthis_button_reddit"></a>');
```

Comment: Even better: just append a single string containing all those elements.

Comment: @Andy - Agreed *for this example*, but might be something else at play here.  A single string for the anchors would be a cached document fragment giving a decent performance boost here if there were a lot of `.addthis_toolbox` elements, but wasn't sure what the "..." part of the question was :)

Comment: @Andy: yes, that's the best possible way performance-wise but it'll decrease readability.

Comment: @Salman - Strings can be `"string part 1"` + (newline) + `"string part 2"`...not sure how it'd decrease readability any.  Readability is relative though, there are reasons *not* to use `with`, you can see both sides here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement