# with (window) {} doesn't work for new pop-up window in IE

Tags: javascript

I open a window, and want to perform some calculation on some condition.
Problem is in IE,  only first call of `test` (from `ready`) is performed from new window, 
but subsequent calls of `test` (set with setTimeout) are executed in parent window and not for new window (i.e. `win`).

It works fine in FF.

illustrating code (this code is in parent window):

```
var win = window.open(some_url, window_name, argument_string);

with (win) {
    function test() {
        alreadyrunflag += 1;
        if (alreadyrunflag < 10) {
            window.setTimeout(function() { test(); }, 500);
        }else { 
            //perform calculation
        }
    }

    jQuery(win.document).ready(function() {
        alreadyrunflag = 0
        test();          
    });
}
```

Comment: Why did you place a function declaration inside a `with` statement? Did you declare the `alreadyrunflag`? You don't need to prefix the `setTimeout` call with `window.`, it is a global member anyway. You don't need to wrap your function call inside a function. Just `setTimeout( test, 500 )` is OK.

Comment: yes I declare alreadyrunflag in with block

Comment: You declare it in with block? What does that mean? Are you declaring it like so: `var alreadyrunflag;`. If yes, is that declaration in the same scope as the code above?

Answer (score 5):

I would **strongly** recommend against using `with` in this situation (and, frankly, almost any other). Instead, simply write `win.` everywhere necessary. Like Eric Meyer, I'm [not a huge fan](http://meyerweb.com/eric/comment/chech.html) of "considered harmful" essays, but [this one](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) by Douglas Crockford I'm in full agreement with.

`with` modifies the "scope chain" in a way that it takes a seriously advanced knowledge of JavaScript to understand fully. See Crockford's essay for details. It also introduces speed penalties (though granted, while I've heard people rant about them, I doubt the costs are really *that* high). The effects on maintainability are just unacceptable. Also, you can't use it in the new strict mode ([MDC link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode)), which is a useful mode that helps you avoid some common bugs.

In this case, it seems to me that the scope chain should resolve in the way you're expecting (and the way Firefox apparently is doing it), but frankly I'm not shocked at all that IE's JScript implementation doesn't handle it the same way. And/or it may be an issue with which `jQuery` ends up getting used (the one in the opening window or the one in the just-opened window; you can't be sure, and it would be timing-dependent...yuck).

Comment: Indeed. E.g., look at `window.setTimeout`: this might resolve to `win.window.setTimeout`, or just `window.setTimeout`.

Comment: Why IE is so (rude)! (its from my experience of javascript problems with IE.)

Comment: @Shanta: IE does have serious issues, there's no question. :-) A lof of it improved in IE8 and the signs are good for IE9. Finally. But in fairness to Microsoft, let's remember that IE is also the reason we have several really useful features (Microsoft's IE innovations that have since been adopted by other browsers -- and by the W3C -- include the basis of Ajax [`XMLHttpRequest`] and `innerHTML`, without which a lot of the current web would be a lot harder to write). So okay, others probably would have done it if Microsoft hadn't, but still, they *did* -- and they did it very early on...

Comment: @Marcel: A *very* good point. It would resolve to `win.window.setTimeout` (in a compliant implementation) but that's not how most of us would read it! And the same thing applies to `jQuery` -- is that the jQuery in the outer window, or the `jQuery` in the inner window? Odds are it would depend on timing (whether the new window had finished retrieving and parsing the jQuery script file). **Yuck**

Comment: I totally agree with you about those innovations (after all, IE 6 was in its days a real improvement over many other browsers), but why on earth couldn't they implement there own `innerHTML` in a consistent way? Oh, and Shanta's braces weren't mismatched, as I erroneously thought, though a line without a statement (only a comment) doesn't get interpreted as an `else` statement (but of course this is only an example, the real code obviously includes a statement (block)).

Answer (score 4):

Putting a `function` declaration in a structure like `if`, `for` or `with`—anywhere other than directly inside a function body or global scope—is invalid in ECMAScript on a basic grammar level. Browsers typically let you get away with it, but what actually happens when you do varies from browser to browser, so you should never rely on it.

This case demonstrates one of the problems: in Firefox, the `function` statement is interpreted as the non-standard Mozilla JavaScript extension `FunctionStatement`, which treats it as if you'd used a `FunctionExpression`, evaluated inline when you expected.

But in IE, the `function` statement is interpreted in the same way as a kosher `FunctionDeclaration` and ‘hoisted’: evaluated at the start of the function that contains it. It does not gain the `with` statement's value as an extra scope (and even if it did, `win` hasn't been assigned yet, so you'd be putting `undefined` on the scope chain!).

So you *could* get around it by using the `FunctionExpression` explicitly:

```
with (win) {
    test= function() { ... };
}
```

But I'd seriously not recommend it. As TJ said, `with` absolutely sucks. It's abolished in ECMAScript Fifth Edition's Strict Mode. Don't use it. (And the timing issues mentioned in the comments. Yuck indeed.)

If you really want to inject `test` into the child window, say so directly: `win.test= function() { ... };`. However, I don't see any need to do so here. You can perfectly well look at the child window from outside without having to put a copy of the function in a property of the child window. Even if you do so, it won't change the scope of the code in the function. And giving documents a copy of functions from other documents is dodgy as in IE, if a document is unloaded, all the functions defined in that document break.

Comment: +1 Also a **very** good point. I missed the declaration at first, only saw the expressions.

Comment: `with` has its uses, but this aint one of them.

Comment: @Tim: Indeed, see [Are there legitimate uses for JavaScript's “with” statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement)