# document.form[0] does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html

```
function func(){
    with (document.forms[0]){
        inputid.value = "text"; //Works!
        spanid.innerHTML = "text"; //Err, spanid is not defined.
    }
}
```

This is not working in Firefox but it is in IE7. I debug in Firebug, `spanid is not defined`, but I can use `document.getElementById("spanid")` to select this element. I just don't know why? The input element works fine!

Comment: At what point are you calling it? It may not be initializing.

Comment: I wouldn't be, since I use the inputid and spanid in the same function. The inputid works but the spanid does not.

Comment: That's not even valid syntax, and what does spanid have to do with document.forms[0]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `document.forms[0]` (notice the **s** on form)

**EDIT**

Since the answers aren't rolling in on this one, here's my suggestion. Simply it. Use the methods you're familiar with and don't waste time trying to get this to work.

```
function YourFunction()
{
    var objSpan = document.getElementById([Insert Element ID]);
    var objInput = document.getElementById([Insert Element ID]);

    objSpan.InnerHTML = "text";
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think that is why people don't suggest with()

Comment: @Desheng there are very few real needs for `with`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement

Answer (score 0):

IE sticks all elements with IDs as properties on the global scope.  Firefox does not do that in standards mode (but does in quirks mode).

Comment: @Quentin Yes, but `document.forms[0]` doesn't get random divs hanging off it.  Only some HTML elements end up with their id/name as properties on a `<form>`, and `<div>` is not in that set.