# Mocking a constructor (or other function) in a Node.js module outside of this module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, tdd, mocking

I'm using Jasmine to write my tests, but I guess I'd have this problem with any other testing framework. Let's say that we have a module `foo` with two functions, `Bar` and `Baz`, which are constructors (but could be just normal functions):

```
var Bar = exports.Bar = function Bar() {
  this.baz = new Baz();
};

var Baz = exports.Baz = function Baz() {

};
```

Now I would like to test `Bar`, but with a fake `Baz` implementation:

```
var foo = require('foo');

describe("foo.Bar", function() {
  it("initializes its own Baz", function() {
    spyOn(foo, 'Baz'); // this replaces foo.Baz with a fake implementation
    var bar = new foo.Bar();
    expect(foo.Baz).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The problem is that this test will fail, because `Bar` instantiates a new `Baz` using the variable `Baz`, which cannot be changed from outside. The only thing that got swapped by using `spyOn()` is `exports.Baz`.

The obvious solution is to write `this.baz = new exports.Baz();` but it kind of feels awkward. If I have more functions which I want to use inside my module, I would have to always call all of them using the `exports.` prefix. Is there any other approach here?

Comment: Try `spyOn(window, 'Baz');` and `expect(window.Baz).toHaveBeenCalled();'.

Comment: @Prusse, I guess Node does not have the `window` object.

Comment: Sorry, but if there is a global object you could use it in place.

Comment: @Prusse, I'm afraid I don't get it. What global object? Isn't having a module system about not having global objects?

Answer (score 1):

If you can somehow decouple these two classes, like allow other implementation of the Baz class to be given to bar, then I think that's the best way and you should go for it.

---

But if you really want to be able to be able to refer to `exports.Baz` as `Baz`, then there's one way that I could think of, using `with`.

It is said that using `with` is generally a bad practice and should be avoided, I wouldn't use it in my own code, but this is one way to solve it and can even be [a legimate use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement), as long as you know what you are doing.

Here it goes:

```
with(exports) {

    exports.Bar = function Bar() {
        console.log('this is bar!');
        this.baz = new Baz();
    };

    exports.Baz = function Baz() {
        console.log('original baz!');
    };

}
```

In another module if you change `foo.Baz` to something else, `Baz` inside foo will also look up to it.

I would still recommend finding a way to make these two classes independent of each other and then you can just give Bar whatever implementation of Baz you want.

Comment: Using `with` is interesting but too hackish I guess. I would prefer not to decouple the two "classes" because `Baz` is never instantiated outside of `Bar`. You could say that maybe I shouldn't test `Baz` then as it's an internal implementation detail but actually the behaviour of the whole system is quite complex and I need more fine-grained tests. Thanks for the tips anyway.