# Why declare variables in with outside access to?

Tags: javascript, with-statement

code is:

```
with(location)
    {
        var url=href+"aaa";    
    }
alert(url);
```

the variable `url` declare in `with`,but it can access outside with,why?

Comment: with is not a function, so it doesn't introduce a new variable scope. it just changes what `this` refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, there is no block-level scoping; only function-level scoping. Take these two examples:

```
if (true) {
    var a = 5;
}

alert(a); // 5

// ...

function foo() {
    var a = 5;
}

foo();

alert(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `var url;` is hoisted to the top of the function block. JavaScript doesn't have block-level scoping, only closure-level (functions).

Answer (score 2):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/185283/548696

The problem is that variables defined within this block are nit scoped to this block (only the object you will enclose after `with` is).

To achieve block-level scoping, do something like that:

```
with({"url": href+"aaa"}) {
    // url is available here    
}
alert(url); // but not here
```

or rather use [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#let_statement), as `with` is considered harmful:

```
let (url = href + "aaa"){
    // url available here
}
// but not here
```