# JavaScript 'use strict'; inside functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, strict

Tested some js code in **Chrome Dev Console** and I'm a bit confused.

I know that in **strict mode** functions that are not methods of an object when referred to **this** keyword should receive **undefined** instead of global object.

```
function test(){
    "use strict";
    return this===undefined;}
test();
```

Outputs **false**.

```
"use strict";
function test(){
    return this===undefined;}
test();
```

Still **false**.

```
(function test(){
    "use strict";
    return this===undefined;}());
```

Outputs **true**.

Just wanted to clarify. ʕ •ᴥ•ʔ I'm new to js.

Comment: please read a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Comment: @hexblot this doesn't answer the question though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the Chromium Developer Console that causes `this` to still refer to the global object. The same code works as specified with `javascript:` in the location bar, and in documents.

You can test that like so (2 console inputs):

```
var global = (function () { return this; }());

"use strict";
function test () { return this === global; }
test();
```

and (one or more console inputs)

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
  'function test () { "use strict"; return this === undefined; }; console.log(test());'
));
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Tested in Chromium Version 25.0.1364.97 Debian 7.0 (183676).

Comment: Your first test is a broken test. Even if you run that in a script tag instead of the console, you will still get `true`, because `"use strict"` must be the *first* line in it's scope. Your example has it coming after `var global ...`, so the directive is ignored (as per the spec).

Comment: @NathanWall No, see my clarification. I suggest you use `debugger;` in the function to inspect the call stack.

Answer (score 3):

What you have noticed is simply a side-effect of the way the developer console works. When you enter code there, this is effectively what happens (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976785/790695) for more details):

```
eval.call(null, "with (window) { \
                     function test() { \
                         'use strict'; \
                         console.log(this); \
                     } test(); \
                 }");
```

This is an *indirect* call to `eval`, which means it will always execute in the global execution context (in the browser, that's `window`).

Effectively, the function is bound to the global object and therefore `this` holds a reference to the global object, as if you did this in a web page (rather than in the console):

```
function test(){
    "use strict";
    return this === undefined;
}

test(); // true
test.call(window); // false
```

Comment: An object like that referred to by `window` *is* *not* an execution context. An execution context is an abstract program entity; it has a *scope chain* with objects in it.  In this case, it would be the `with` statement that inserts the object referred to by `window` in the scope chain for the context of the `test()` call.

Comment: @PointedEars - Yes, of course. I could have said "the lexical environment's environment record to which the `window` object belongs" but the way I put it was simpler and I think still gets the point across. And the `with` statement makes no difference in this case - it's the way that `eval` is called that affects the context in which its argument is evaluated.

Comment: The `with` statement here *might* be substantial; it certainly is if you assume (IMO mistakenly) that the `window` host property of the global object always refers to the global object.  Because then the `test()` call would be equivalent to `global.window.test()`, where `global` would be a stand-in for the standard reference to the global object.

Answer (score 1):

Everything's fine. If you run your code via some HTML page (not a dev console), results meet expectations (always `this===undefined`).

Additionally in latest Firefox (Firebug):

```
function test(){
    "use strict";
    return this===undefined;}
test(); 
>> true
```

So this seems to be just another Chrome's bug (feature?). It feels like it has a slightly different approach to the code that is passed via dev console.

Also note that order matters:

```
<script>
    console.log( 'Me First!' );

    "use strict";

    function test(){
        console.log( this );
    }
    test();

</script>

>>> "Me First!"
>>> Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

But:

```
<script>
    "use strict";

    console.log( 'Me later!' );

    function test(){
        console.log( this );
    }
    test();

</script>

>>> undefined
>>> "Me later!"
```